# One Ring to rule them all. One String to contain them all

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Objectives: Output a String which contains every positive integer strictly below 1000.

The obvious answer would be to concatenate every one of them, and that would create a String of 2890 characters (thanks manatwork), to avoid this kind of easy answer, the length of the string must be under 1500 characters.
Here is a straightforward Java code which outputs a 1200 chars String.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: fab
 * Date: 05/11/13
 * Time: 09:53
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class AStringToContainThemAll {

    @Test
    public void testsubStrings() throws Exception {
        String a = generateNewString();
        boolean cool = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            assertTrue(a.contains(Integer.toString(i)));
        }
    }

    private String generateNewString() {
        List<Integer> myTree = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String finalString = new String("100");
        for (int i = 10; i < 1000; i++) {
            myTree.add(i);
        }
        while (myTree.size() > 0) {
            if (finalString.contains(Integer.toString(myTree.get(0)))) {
                myTree.remove(0);
            } else {
                String substringLong = finalString.substring(finalString.length() - 2, finalString.length());
                boolean found = false;
                loop:
                for (Integer integer : myTree) {
                    if (integer.toString().startsWith(substringLong) && !finalString.contains(integer.toString())) {
                        finalString = finalString.concat(integer.toString().substring(2, 3));
                        myTree.remove(integer);
                        found = true;
                        break loop;
                    }
                }
                if(! found){
                    finalString = finalString.concat(myTree.get(0).toString());
                    myTree.remove(0);
                }
            }


        }
        return finalString;
    }
}
```

Shortest code win, bonus point for the shortest String!

Comment: The optimal string is 1002 characters long.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm interested, how did you figure that out?

Comment: Basically you're asking for a [de Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) `B(10, 3)`, but because you don't allow cyclic wrapping it's necessary to repeat the first two characters.

Comment: But I want the string to contain 1, 2 or 56, not necessarily 001 002 and 056.

Comment: How you calculated that maximum 2907? (`([*0..999]*'').size` gives 2890 in `ruby`.)

Comment: @manatwork I just added every 1 digit number, 2-digit numbers and 3-digit numbers, but I failed terribly at calculating it in my head (I counted 99 2-digit numbers, and 9 mono-digit numbers)

Comment: You're right, it should be possible to shorten the output string to 999 chars by picking the lexicographically first de Bruijn sequence, moving two leading zeroes to the end, and removing the remaining leading zero.

Comment: #Java-134 chars class a{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.println("a String which contains every positive integer strictly below 1000");}} Output (66 chars):
>a String which contains every positive integer strictly below 1000 Did I approach the problem the wrong way?

Comment: nit-picking edit because I'm a LotR fan :P

Comment: this is more of a mathematics problem

Comment: Since this is code-golf the accepted answer should go to the shortest, which is currently Howard's and not mine.

Comment: @PeterTaylor ok, your answer was just more clever.

Comment: The following is also an interesting approach, and technically not correct in terms of the question, as it is not complying to the maximum 1500 characters condition, and the output string is not human-readable. Using old-school methods that I figured out when I was hacking Civilization I maps (hehehe), I found that, for example, if you had 4000 gold in your treasury, this was stored in 2 digits only, namely, 1 digit representing 15 * 256, and another digit representing the modulus of 4000 by 15, namely 160. So, using this algorithm, you can store each number in 1 digit from 0 until you get to

Comment: @Justin You can save 24 bytes ... the string only has to contain `every positive integer strictly below 1000`.

Comment: This contest would be cooler if it asked for the shortest [size of code] + [size of output].

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Golfscript - 13 bytes, 1315 output

```
991,{`.$2>>},
```

The above selects those numbers from *0-990* whose first digit is the largest digit of the number, i.e. the last digit of the sorted string representation is lexicographically less than the string itself. The logic is the following:

For a 3 digit number *abc*, if *a* is not the largest digit of the number, the number my be skipped, because it will be covered by one of two cases later on:

1. ***b < c*** (e.g. *123*)
   Because *c* is the largest digit, the number *cab* will not be skipped. In this example *312* will not be skipped, nor will the next value *313*, which when concatenated (*312 313*) contains *123*.
2. ***b ≥ c*** (e.g. *132*)
   Because *b* is the largest digit, the number *bca* will not be skipped. In this example *321* will not be skipped, nor will the next value *322*, which when concatenated (*321 322*) contains *132*. If *b = c* (e.g. *122*), this case also applies. The value *bca* will not be skipped, as before, and because *a* is necessarily less than *b*, *bc<a+1>* will not be skipped either. In this example, *221 222* contains *122*.

Because the above code tests the third digit, rather than strictly the last, all values from *0-99* are included in the result. The values from *1-99* may be skipped, however, because if every 3-digit sequence is present, then every 1-digit and 2-digit sequence must also be present.

The values from *991-999* may also be skipped, as the are generated by (*909 910*, *919 920*, ... *989 990*).

At 1315 bytes of output, this is comfortably under the problem's specification of less than 1500.

Output:

```
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101110111200201202210211212220221222300301302303310311312313320321322323330331332333400401402403404410411412413414420421422423424430431432433434440441442443444500501502503504505510511512513514515520521522523524525530531532533534535540541542543544545550551552553554555600601602603604605606610611612613614615616620621622623624625626630631632633634635636640641642643644645646650651652653654655656660661662663664665666700701702703704705706707710711712713714715716717720721722723724725726727730731732733734735736737740741742743744745746747750751752753754755756757760761762763764765766767770771772773774775776777800801802803804805806807808810811812813814815816817818820821822823824825826827828830831832833834835836837838840841842843844845846847848850851852853854855856857858860861862863864865866867868870871872873874875876877878880881882883884885886887888900901902903904905906907908909910911912913914915916917918919920921922923924925926927928929930931932933934935936937938939940941942943944945946947948949950951952953954955956957958959960961962963964965966967968969970971972973974975976977978979980981982983984985986987988989990
```

#### Variation #1

**14 bytes, 1233 output**

```
991,{`.$-1>>},
```

By selecting strictly the last digit for comparison, rather than the third, many of the unnecessary values less than *100* are eliminated, shortening the resulting string.

```
101120212230313233404142434450515253545560616263646566707172737475767780818283848586878890919293949596979899100101110111200201202210211212220221222300301302303310311312313320321322323330331332333400401402403404410411412413414420421422423424430431432433434440441442443444500501502503504505510511512513514515520521522523524525530531532533534535540541542543544545550551552553554555600601602603604605606610611612613614615616620621622623624625626630631632633634635636640641642643644645646650651652653654655656660661662663664665666700701702703704705706707710711712713714715716717720721722723724725726727730731732733734735736737740741742743744745746747750751752753754755756757760761762763764765766767770771772773774775776777800801802803804805806807808810811812813814815816817818820821822823824825826827828830831832833834835836837838840841842843844845846847848850851852853854855856857858860861862863864865866867868870871872873874875876877878880881882883884885886887888900901902903904905906907908909910911912913914915916917918919920921922923924925926927928929930931932933934935936937938939940941942943944945946947948949950951952953954955956957958959960961962963964965966967968969970971972973974975976977978979980981982983984985986987988989990
```

#### Variation #2

**16 bytes, 1127 output**

```
991,99>{`.$2>>},
```

By prying off all values less than *99* beforehand, the resulting string can be shortened even more.

```
99100101110111200201202210211212220221222300301302303310311312313320321322323330331332333400401402403404410411412413414420421422423424430431432433434440441442443444500501502503504505510511512513514515520521522523524525530531532533534535540541542543544545550551552553554555600601602603604605606610611612613614615616620621622623624625626630631632633634635636640641642643644645646650651652653654655656660661662663664665666700701702703704705706707710711712713714715716717720721722723724725726727730731732733734735736737740741742743744745746747750751752753754755756757760761762763764765766767770771772773774775776777800801802803804805806807808810811812813814815816817818820821822823824825826827828830831832833834835836837838840841842843844845846847848850851852853854855856857858860861862863864865866867868870871872873874875876877878880881882883884885886887888900901902903904905906907908909910911912913914915916917918919920921922923924925926927928929930931932933934935936937938939940941942943944945946947948949950951952953954955956957958959960961962963964965966967968969970971972973974975976977978979980981982983984985986987988989990
```

---

### Golfscript - 19 bytes, 1016 output

```
910,99>{`.2$\?)>+}/
```

The above counts from *99* to *909*, adding any value that hasn't already appeared (*909* would normally be the last value added in this way). Moving *99* to the front is an optimization to avoid needing *910* at the back.

Output:

```
99100101102103104105106107108109111112113114115116117118119120122123124125126127128129130132133134135136137138139140142143144145146147148149150152153154155156157158159160162163164165166167168169170172173174175176177178179180182183184185186187188189190192193194195196197198199200202203204205206207208209222223224225226227228229230233234235236237238239240243244245246247248249250253254255256257258259260263264265266267268269270273274275276277278279280283284285286287288289290293294295296297298299300303304305306307308309333334335336337338339340344345346347348349350354355356357358359360364365366367368369370374375376377378379380384385386387388389390394395396397398399400404405406407408409444445446447448449450455456457458459460465466467468469470475476477478479480485486487488489490495496497498499500505506507508509555556557558559560566567568569570576577578579580586587588589590596597598599600606607608609666667668669670677678679680687688689690697698699700707708709777778779780788789790798799800808809888889890899900909
```

---

### Golfscript 26 bytes, 999 output

```
909.,99>{`..$.2><3$@?+>+}/
```

Note that the *1016* character string produced by the previous solution is nearly optimal, except for having two extra
digits for each multiple of *111* (i.e. `11111` instead of `111`, `22222` instead of `222`, etc.). The solution can be
made optimal by removing these extra digits (only inserting one digit at each of these values, instead of three), and by
rotating `909` to the front, eliminating a `9` (this differs from the previous versions, which moved `9100` to the back instead).

Unrolled and commented:

```
909.,99>  # add 909 to the stack, and duplicate
          # create an array from 0..908, and 
          # remove the first 99 elements (99..908)
{
  `..     # stringify, duplicate twice

  $.2><   # non-divisibility by 111 check
          # true if the last char of the sorted
          # string is greater than the first char

  3$@?    # first position of this number in
          # the total string so far (-1 if not found)

  +>      # add the two previous results,
          # and slice from that point
          # (see explanation below)

  +       # concat what remains to the total string

}/        # loop over the set
```

The logic to choose which characters are appended follows three cases:

1. ***111* ∤ *n*, *n* ⊄ *s***
   The value from the first check is *1*, and from the second *-1*.
   The slice will begin starting from index *0*; it will return the whole string.
2. ***111* ∤ *n*, *n* ⊂ *s***
   The value from the first check is *1*, and from the second something *≥ 2*.
   The slice will begin staring from index *≥ 3*; it will return an empty string.
3. ***111* ∣ *n*, *n* ⊄ *s***
   The value from the first check is *0*, and from the second *-1*.
   The slice will begin starting from index *-1*; it will return the last character only.

The sum of the logic is that any value which hasn't yet appeared will be appended in whole - unless it is a multiple of *111*, in which case only one character will be appended. All other values will be ignored.

Note that the string produced is different than the optimal one produced by [Peter Taylor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/13091/4098).

History:

```
899,{101+.111%{`.2$\?0<*}{3/9%}if+}/

899,{101+`.2$\?0<\.~111%2*)<*+}/0

899,{101+`.2$\?0<\..2>-!2*>*+}/0

899,{101+`...2>|,1|<2$@?0<*+}/0

999,{`..$.2>>2*>2$@?0<*+}/3>0

899,{101+`..$.2><3$@?+>+}/0
```

Output:

```
909910010110210310410510610710810911121131141151161171181191201221231241251261271281291301321331341351361371381391401421431441451461471481491501521531541551561571581591601621631641651661671681691701721731741751761771781791801821831841851861871881891901921931941951961971981992002022032042052062072082092223224225226227228229230233234235236237238239240243244245246247248249250253254255256257258259260263264265266267268269270273274275276277278279280283284285286287288289290293294295296297298299300303304305306307308309333433533633733833934034434534634734834935035435535635735835936036436536636736836937037437537637737837938038438538638738838939039439539639739839940040440540640740840944454464474484494504554564574584594604654664674684694704754764774784794804854864874884894904954964974984995005055065075085095556557558559560566567568569570576577578579580586587588589590596597598599600606607608609666766866967067767867968068768868969069769869970070770870977787797807887897907987998008088098889890899900
```

Answer (score 46):

### GolfScript (<strike>35 31</strike> 26 chars)

```
10,{:x),{:&x=x+,{x&@}/}/}/
```

Output is

```
000100110111200201210211220221222300301302310311312320321322330331332333400401402403410411412413420421422423430431432433440441442443444500501502503504510511512513514520521522523524530531532533534540541542543544550551552553554555600601602603604605610611612613614615620621622623624625630631632633634635640641642643644645650651652653654655660661662663664665666700701702703704705706710711712713714715716720721722723724725726730731732733734735736740741742743744745746750751752753754755756760761762763764765766770771772773774775776777800801802803804805806807810811812813814815816817820821822823824825826827830831832833834835836837840841842843844845846847850851852853854855856857860861862863864865866867870871872873874875876877880881882883884885886887888900901902903904905906907908910911912913914915916917918920921922923924925926927928930931932933934935936937938940941942943944945946947948950951952953954955956957958960961962963964965966967968970971972973974975976977978980981982983984985986987988990991992993994995996997998999
```

(1020 chars) This is a variant on the Lyndon word concatenation approach: rather than use the primitive 1-char words it uses multiples of 111 for shorter code but repeated occurrences of those numbers; and rather than use minimal elements of the conjugacy groups it uses maximal elements, because that shortens the loops.

---

```
10,:^{:x^>{x.@:&<+^>{.x>{x&@}*}/}/}%3>0.
```

at 40 chars (can probably still be improved) generates an optimal string, which is of length 999 chars:

```
100200300400500600700800901101201301401501601701801902102202302402502602702802903103203303403503603703803904104204304404504604704804905105205305405505605705805906106206306406506606706806907107207307407507607707807908108208308408508608708808909109209309409509609709809911121131141151161171181191221231241251261271281291321331341351361371381391421431441451461471481491521531541551561571581591621631641651661671681691721731741751761771781791821831841851861871881891921931941951961971981992223224225226227228229233234235236237238239243244245246247248249253254255256257258259263264265266267268269273274275276277278279283284285286287288289293294295296297298299333433533633733833934434534634734834935435535635735835936436536636736836937437537637737837938438538638738838939439539639739839944454464474484494554564574584594654664674684694754764774784794854864874884894954964974984995556557558559566567568569576577578579586587588589596597598599666766866967767867968768868969769869977787797887897987998889899900
```

Trying to make this do reverse strings runs into problems with omitting the multiples of 111.

To see that 999 is the optimal length (since my brief comments above don't convince everyone), start from the full de Bruijn sequence which (taken as a cyclic string) contains every 3-digit sequence of characters from 0 to 9. Since there are 1000 of them, it must be at least 1000 characters long; that it can be precisely 1000 characters long is usually proven by an Eulerian walk on a graph whose nodes are two-digit sequences `xy` with 10 edges, each labelled with one digit `z`, which take `xy` to `yz`.

We don't need sequences beginning `0`, so given a de Bruijn sequence we can rotate to put `000` at the end. Then we don't need either of the sequences which wrap round to the beginning, but we do need two of the `0`s to finish the sequence starting with the digit before `000`, so we can delete one of them to get a 999-character string. Every remaining `0` is used in a number which doesn't begin with `0`.

Comment: That's truly impressive!!

Comment: I'd prefer to use a filtering or generative approach. For the pseudo-Lyndon approach I've got the generative approach down to 32 chars: `10,:^{:x^>{x.@:&<+^>{x&@}/}/}/0.` Varying that for true Lyndon words gives `10,:^{:x^>{x.@:&<+^>{.x>{x&@}*}/}/}%3>0.` (40 chars) for the optimal string.

Comment: Can you get the optimal string shorter by not using leading zeros for numbers below 100?

Comment: @Random832 I'm pretty sure you can't. You have to include the numbers 100, 200, ... 900, so the minimal string is certainly going to have eight occurances of 00X (one can be at the far right, as above). Note that the optimal string given doesn't contain "001".

Comment: Normally I don't upvote code I don't understand, but in this case I'm upvoting it *because* I don't understand.  Bravo.

Comment: Hmm... why should 999 characters be the minimum? you only need 899 3-character sequences and each 2 character-sequence is already contained in it, theoretically

Answer (score 30):

#### GolfScript, 17 characters

```
999,{`1$1$?0<*+}/
```

Plain approach to add each number if not already present in the string (note: 999 is not checked or added, but contained already in the output).

Output is 1133 characters:

```
01234567891011131415161718192021222425262728293032333536373839404344464748495054555758596065666869707677798087889099100102103104105106107108109110112114115116117118119120124125126127128129130132133134135136137138139140142143144145146147148149150152153154155156157158159160162163164165166167168169170172173174175176177178179180182183184185186187188189190193194195196197198199200203204205206207208209219220221223225226227228229230231235236237238239240243244245246247248249250253254255256257258259260263264265266267268269270273274275276277278279280283284285286287288289290294295296297298299300304305306307308309311329330332334336337338339340342346347348349350354355356357358359360364365366367368369370374375376377378379380384385386387388389390395396397398399400405406407408409422439440443445447448449450453457458459460465466467468469470475476477478479480485486487488489490496497498499500506507508509533549550554556558559560564568569570576577578579580586587588589590597598599600607608609644659660665667669670675679680687688689690698699700708709755769770776778780786790797799800809866877879880887888897898899900908932943954965976979987989
```

Answer (score 22):

I don't have any code, but I thought someone might appreciate this intuitive proof that 999 characters is the lower bound to the length of the output:

First, every 1- and 2-digit number is part of a 3-digit number, so ignore everything less than 100. 100-999 inclusive is 900 3-digit numbers.

The most optimal way to solve the problem is if every character is used as much as possible. That means the numbers overlap as much as possible, like this:

```
123
 234
  345
```

The first number will therefore add 3 characters, and each subsequent number will add 1 character. That gives 3 + 899 = 902 characters as a lower bound.

However, when there is a zero, we can't use it to start a new 3-digit number. We can reuse it in the middle of another 3-digit number though, as long as it is not followed by another zero:

```
120
 203  <- Ok.
  034 <- not a number 100-999.
```

But:

```
100
 002  <- not a number 100-999.
  023 <- not a number 100-999.
```

Therefore, each zero which appears in the output extends the output by 1 character - except for the last two characters which may be zero as they do not overlap any further numbers:

```
???
 ??0
  ?00
```

There are 81 numbers with strictly one zero in the middle (?0?), 81 with strictly one zero at the end (??0), and 9 with two zeros (?00).

Every ??0 number can share a zero with either a ?0? number or a ?00 number, but not both. ?0? and ?00 can never share zeros, so there must be at least 81 + 9*2 zeros in the output.

This gives a lower bound of 3 + 899 + 81 + 9*2 - 2 = 999 characters.

Apologies if this is considered off-topic, but it was too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence.

Comment: It's kinda funny to notice that storing every number up to 999 in a string makes it 999 characters long. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that storing every number up to 99 makes it a 100 characters long.

Comment: By the same argument the lower bound is 2 + 89 + 9 - 1 = 99 but this does not prove 99 is possible, only that 98 isn't.

Answer (score 18):

### Perl, <del>37 34 33</del> 32 (<del>1136</del> 1132 characters)

```perl
for$@(1..999){$_.=$@x!/$@/}print
```

<del>for$@(1..999){$_.=$@if!/$@/}print</del>

<del>for$i(1..999){$_.=$i if!/$i/}print</del>

<del>for(1..1e3){$s.=$_ if$s!~/$_/}print$s</del>

Outputs:

```
12345678910111314151617181920212224252627282930323335363738394043444647484950545557585960656668697076777980878890991001021031041051061071081091101121141151161171181191201241251261271281291301321331341351361371381391401421431441451461471481491501521531541551561571581591601621631641651661671681691701721731741751761771781791801821831841851861871881891901931941951961971981992002032042052062072082092192202212232252262272282292302312352362372382392402432442452462472482492502532542552562572582592602632642652662672682692702732742752762772782792802832842852862872882892902942952962972982993003043053063073083093113293303323343363373383393403423463473483493503543553563573583593603643653663673683693703743753763773783793803843853863873883893903953963973983994004054064074084094224394404434454474484494504534574584594604654664674684694704754764774784794804854864874884894904964974984995005065075085095335495505545565585595605645685695705765775785795805865875885895905975985996006076086096446596606656676696706756796806876886896906986997007087097557697707767787807867907977998008098668778798808878888978988999009089329439549659769799879891000
```

#### Shorter string: <del>38 37</del> 34 (1020 characters):

```perl
$_.=$@x!/$@/while$@=--$@%1e3;print
```

<del>for($@=1e3;$@--;){$_.=$@if!/$@/}print</del>

<del>for($i=1e3;$i--;){$_.=$i if!/$i/}print</del>

Outputs:

```
999998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888887886885884883882881880877876875874873872871870867866865864863862861860857856855854853852851850847846845844843842841840837836835834833832831830827826825824823822821820817816815814813812811810807806805804803802801800777776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555554553552551550544543542541540534533532531530524523522521520514513512511510504503502501500444443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333332331330322321320312311310302301300222221220211210201200111110101100
```

Still not happy with the duplication especially the 99999 at the beginning! I think many more checks would create a lot more code though...

Edit: Added suggestion from @Peter Taylor

Edit 2: Some great suggestions from @primo! Thank you

Comment: Nice trick to write 1000 as 1e3, but I think it's pointless. The question says “strictly below 1000”, that would mean up to and including 999. (The sample code also processes 0..999.)

Comment: An excellent point! I had a different loop to begin with, I've amended this accordingly! Thanks!

Comment: If you use a non-alphabetic character for your variable can you remove the space?

Comment: A few more minor improvements: instead of `$_.=$@if!/$@/`, you can use string repetition `$_.=$@x!/$@/`. The `for` can be replaced by a `while` as a statement modifier, using a modulo: `...while$@=--$@%1e3`

Comment: String repetition is an amazing trick, making sure to remember that one, the while+modulo took me a bit to get, but is a nice way to save two more, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

### APL (20, output: 1020)

```
{∨/⍺⍷⍵:⍵⋄⍵,⍺}/⍕¨⍳999
```

Explanation:

- `{∨/⍺⍷⍵:⍵⋄⍵,⍺}`: if `⍺` is a substring of `⍵`, return `⍵`, else return `⍵,⍺`
- `/`: reduce over
- `⍕¨`: the string representation of each of
- `⍳999`: the integers from `1` to `999`.

Output:

```
9999989979969959949939929919909889879869859849839829819809789779769759749739729719709689679669659649639629619609589579569
      55954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913
      91291191090890790690590490390290190088888788688588488388288188087787687587487387287187086786686586486386286186085785
      68558548538528518508478468458448438428418408378368358348338328318308278268258248238228218208178168158148138128118108
      07806805804803802801800777776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735
      73473373273173072672572472372272172071671571471371271171070670570470370270170066666566466366266166065565465365265165
      06456446436426416406356346336326316306256246236226216206156146136126116106056046036026016005555545535525515505445435
      42541540534533532531530524523522521520514513512511510504503502501500444443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411
      410403402401400333332331330322321320312311310302301300222221220211210201200111110101100
```

### APL (41, output: 999)

```
'0',⍨⊃{⍵,⍺⍴⍨(1=⍴∪⍺)∨3×~∨/⍺⍷⍵}/⌽⍕¨100+⍳898
```

Explanation:

- `⌽⍕¨100+⍳898`: `('999' '998' ... '101')` (in reverse order, because reduction goes right to left in APL, i.e. `F/a b c ≡ a F (b F c)`)
- `/`: reduce
- `⍵,⍺⍴⍨`: right argument, followed by the first `N` characters of the left argument, where `N` is:
- `3×~∨/⍺⍷⍵`: `3` if `⍺` is not a substring of `⍵`, otherwise `0`
- `(1=⍴∪⍺)`: `1` if `⍺` only has one unique characcter, otherwise `0`
- `∨`: greatest common divisor of the previous two values, so: `1` if `⍺` is not already in `⍵` and only has one unique character, `3` if `⍺` is not already in `⍵` but has more than one unique character, `0` otherwise.
- `'0',⍨`: add a zero to the end of the result

Output:

```
10110210310410510610710810911121131141151161171181191201221231241251261271281291301321331341351361371381391401421431441451
      46147148149150152153154155156157158159160162163164165166167168169170172173174175176177178179180182183184185186187188
      18919019219319419519619719819920020220320420520620720820922232242252262272282292302332342352362372382392402432442452
      46247248249250253254255256257258259260263264265266267268269270273274275276277278279280283284285286287288289290293294
      29529629729829930030330430530630730830933343353363373383393403443453463473483493503543553563573583593603643653663673
      68369370374375376377378379380384385386387388389390394395396397398399400404405406407408409444544644744844945045545645
      74584594604654664674684694704754764774784794804854864874884894904954964974984995005055065075085095556557558559560566
      56756856957057657757857958058658758858959059659759859960060660760860966676686696706776786796806876886896906976986997
      00707708709777877978078878979079879980080880988898908999009099100
```

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby: <s>50</s> 46 characters (1020 characters output)

```ruby
s=""
999.downto(0){|i|s[n=i.to_s]||s+=n}
$><<s
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -e 's="";999.downto(0){|i|s[n=i.to_s]||s+=n};$><<s'
999998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888887886885884883882881880877876875874873872871870867866865864863862861860857856855854853852851850847846845844843842841840837836835834833832831830827826825824823822821820817816815814813812811810807806805804803802801800777776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555554553552551550544543542541540534533532531530524523522521520514513512511510504503502501500444443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333332331330322321320312311310302301300222221220211210201200111110101100
```

Test run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -e 's="";999.downto(0){|i|s[n=i.to_s]||s+=n};$><<s' | ruby -ne 'p (0..999).reject{|i|$_[i.to_s]}'
[]
```

### Ruby: <s>102</s> 97 characters (999 characters output)

```ruby
s=""
999.downto(0){|i|s[n=i.to_s]||[2,1].map{|j|n[0,j]==s[-j,j]&&s+=n[j,9]and break}&&s+=n}
$><<s
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -e 's="";999.downto(0){|i|s[n=i.to_s]||[2,1].map{|j|n[0,j]==s[-j,j]&&s+=n[j,9]and break}&&s+=n};$><<s'
999899799699599499399299199098898798698598498398298198097897797697597497397297197096896796696596496396296196095895795695595495395295195094894794694594494394294194093893793693593493393293193092892792692592492392292192091891791691591491391291191090890790690590490390290190088878868858848838828818808778768758748738728718708678668658648638628618608578568558548538528518508478468458448438428418408378368358348338328318308278268258248238228218208178168158148138128118108078068058048038028018007776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666566466366266166065565465365265165064564464364264164063563463363263163062562462362262162061561461361261161060560460360260160055545535525515505445435425415405345335325315305245235225215205145135125115105045035025015004443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333233133032232132031231131030230130022212202112102012001110100
```

Test run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -e 's="";999.downto(0){|i|s[n=i.to_s]||[2,1].map{|j|n[0,j]==s[-j,j]&&s+=n[j,9]and break}&&s+=n};$><<s' | ruby -ne 'p (0..999).reject{|i|$_[i.to_s]}'
[]
```

Comment: Nice idea to go from 999 to 0 and not the opposite way. With this, my Java method outputs  a 1048 characters string (instead of 1200).

Comment: If you're just worried about code length and not output length, you could improve the first one using a string range.  Something like `(?0..?9*3).map{|i|$/[i]||($><<i;$/+=i)}` maybe?

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica (<s>62</s> 64 chars, 1002 output)

Because this makes use of a native function, I appreciate all the more the beauty of shorter solutions from scratch.  Output is 1002 chars long.

```
<< Combinatorica`
"79" <> DeBruijnSequence["0"~CharacterRange~"9", 3]

"799798787770760750740730720710980970960950940930920910108908708608508408308208889998988081009909008007006005004003002000190180170160150140130120119118117116115114113112912812712612512412312213913813713613513413313214914814714614514414314215915815715615515415315216916816716616516416316217917817717617517417317218918818718618518418318219919819719619519419319212111029028027026025024023022922822722622522422392382372362352342332492482472462452442432592582572562552542532692682672662652642632792782772762752742732892882872862852842832992982972962952942932322202103903803703603503403393383373363353349348347346345344359358357356355354369368367366365364379378377376375374389388387386385384399398397396395394343330320310490480470460450449448447446445945845745645546946846746646547947847747647548948848748648549949849749649545444043042041059058057056055955855755695685675665795785775765895885875865995985975965655505405305205106906806706696686679678677689688687699698697676660650640630620610790780779778978879"
```

Comment: you appear to be missing 799 and 997. see http://ideone.com/d07bG2 (or write your own check)

Comment: Good catch. By default, `DeBruijnSequence` assumes cyclic wrapping. Prepending "79", the final two digits, solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 39

```
for(k=i="999";~k.indexOf(--i)?i:k+=i;);
```

1020 character output:

```
999998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888887886885884883882881880877876875874873872871870867866865864863862861860857856855854853852851850847846845844843842841840837836835834833832831830827826825824823822821820817816815814813812811810807806805804803802801800777776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555554553552551550544543542541540534533532531530524523522521520514513512511510504503502501500444443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333332331330322321320312311310302301300222221220211210201200111110101100
```

Verification: `for(i=0;i<1000;i++)console.assert(k.indexOf(i)>=0)`

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 51 chars

```
""<>Table[ToString/@({i,j,k}-1),{i,10},{j,i},{k,i}]
```

Output(1155 chars):

```
000100101110111200201202210211212220221222300301302303310311312313320321322323330331332333400401402403404410411412413414420421422423424430431432433434440441442443444500501502503504505510511512513514515520521522523524525530531532533534535540541542543544545550551552553554555600601602603604605606610611612613614615616620621622623624625626630631632633634635636640641642643644645646650651652653654655656660661662663664665666700701702703704705706707710711712713714715716717720721722723724725726727730731732733734735736737740741742743744745746747750751752753754755756757760761762763764765766767770771772773774775776777800801802803804805806807808810811812813814815816817818820821822823824825826827828830831832833834835836837838840841842843844845846847848850851852853854855856857858860861862863864865866867868870871872873874875876877878880881882883884885886887888900901902903904905906907908909910911912913914915916917918919920921922923924925926927928929930931932933934935936937938939940941942943944945946947948949950951952953954955956957958959960961962963964965966967968969970971972973974975976977978979980981982983984985986987988989990991992993994995996997998999
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: It constructs a list of lists of the form `{i, j, k}` where `i` is from 0 to 9 and `j`, `k` are smaller than `i`. Then it converts the list into a string.

Answer (score 5):

## Python - 53 <del>63</del>, 1134 output

This is pretty brute forcish, but it is valid. Yes it has a leading zero, but it saves two characters by not having `range(1,1000)`.

```
s=''
for i in range(1e3):s+=`i`*(not`i`in s)
print s
```

The above throws a `DeprecationWarning` over the use of 1e3 in the `range()` call, but it saves a character over using 1000.

There is a slightly more optimal length output version as well, by reversing the string at the cost of <del>6</del> 5 characters **(thanks to r.e.s and filmor for the tips)**:

## Python - 58, 1021 output

```
s=''
for i in range(999,9,-1):s+=`i`*(not`i`in s)
print s
```

Comment: I find that your first program has output length 1133, not 1132. In Python 2 (but not Python 3), you can shorten the code to **54** characters by using backticks: `for i in range(999):s+=\`i\`*(not\`i\`in s)`

Comment: Wot? They took out backticks? Guido must have been having an I Hate Perl and Everything that Looks like It day when deciding what to keep.

Comment: You can shorten that by one character by using `range(999,99,-1)` instead of `range(1000)[::-1]`.

Comment: And the tip by r.e.s. still help, `str(i)*(str(i)not in s)` is a bit shorter than `i=str(i);s+=[i,''][i in s]` ;)

Comment: @filmor Made smaller, and smaller again by using `1e3` instead of `1000`

Comment: I find the length of your first program is now 54, not 53, and the second one is 59, not 58. Also, `range(999)` is enough in the first one -- `range(1000)` (or `range(1e3)`) is not needed -- and the output length is 1133, not 1134.

Comment: `range(1e3)` does not work: Python 2.7:`TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.` Python 3.2: `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Also: The output length of your first script is `1133` and the second one is `1020`.

Answer (score 3):

## Java-<s>126</s> 98 chars (Java 6)

```
class b{static{String s="";for(int a=999;a>0;a--)s=s.contains(""+a)?s:s+a;System.out.println(s);}}
```

Output (1020 chars):

```
999998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888887886885884883882881880877876875874873872871870867866865864863862861860857856855854853852851850847846845844843842841840837836835834833832831830827826825824823822821820817816815814813812811810807806805804803802801800777776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555554553552551550544543542541540534533532531530524523522521520514513512511510504503502501500444443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333332331330322321320312311310302301300222221220211210201200111110101100
```

Can reach a good (according to [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13088/a-ring-to-rule-them-all-a-string-to-contain-them-all#comment25855_13088), but later he said 999 was optimal) String length by adding a few chars (+20 chars for <s>147</s> 118):

```
class b{static{String s="";for(int a=999;a>0;a--)s=s.contains(""+a)?s:(a+1)%111==0?s+a%10:s+a;System.out.println(s);}}
```

Output (1002 chars):

```
999899799699599499399299199098898798698598498398298198097897797697597497397297197096896796696596496396296196095895795695595495395295195094894794694594494394294194093893793693593493393293193092892792692592492392292192091891791691591491391291191090890790690590490390290190088878868858848838828818808778768758748738728718708678668658648638628618608578568558548538528518508478468458448438428418408378368358348338328318308278268258248238228218208178168158148138128118108078068058048038028018007776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666566466366266166065565465365265165064564464364264164063563463363263163062562462362262162061561461361261161060560460360260160055545535525515505445435425415405345335325315305245235225215205145135125115105045035025015004443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333233133032232132031231131030230130022212202112102012001110101100
```

**Edit**: Thanks to Fabinout for pointing out that Java 6 can save 28 chars.

Comment: If you want, you can compile with java 6 and use a static block instead of a System.out.println()!!

Comment: @Fabinout Do you mean instead of a `public static void main(String[]a)`? (that would change my code from `...public static void main(String[]c){...` to `...static{...`)

Comment: Yes I do. you can try with Java 6.

Comment: Btw, you should use exit() at the end of your static block if you don't want your program to crash. Even though it's not required in golfing to not crash.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 75 bytes - 1002 output

A sieve approach that returns a minimal solution.

```
(\n->head.filter(\s->and[show k`isInfixOf`s|k<-[1..n]]).map show$[1..])1000
```

Note that this solution is impractically slow.

Comment: You need to include the import of `Data.List` for `isInfixOf`, however you can still save 2 bytes by golfing it some more: 1) Hardcode `n = 1000` 2) Use `all` over `and` and a pointfree version of the predicate 3) use `(!!0)` over `head` 4) Use list-comprehension over combination of `map` & `filter` 5) use `(<$>)` over `map`: ``[s|s<-show<$>[1..],all((`isInfixOf`s).show)[1..1000]]!!0``

Answer (score 2):

## K, 33

```
{$[#ss[x]@y;x;,/x,y]}/["";$!1000]
```

Basically the same as Howards solution - 1133 characters.

```
01234567891011131415161718192021222425262728293032333536373839404344464748495054555758596065666869707677798087889099100102103104105106107108109110112114115116117118119120124125126127128129130132133134135136137138139140142143144145146147148149150152153154155156157158159160162163164165166167168169170172173174175176177178179180182183184185186187188189190193194195196197198199200203204205206207208209219220221223225226227228229230231235236237238239240243244245246247248249250253254255256257258259260263264265266267268269270273274275276277278279280283284285286287288289290294295296297298299300304305306307308309311329330332334336337338339340342346347348349350354355356357358359360364365366367368369370374375376377378379380384385386387388389390395396397398399400405406407408409422439440443445447448449450453457458459460465466467468469470475476477478479480485486487488489490496497498499500506507508509533549550554556558559560564568569570576577578579580586587588589590597598599600607608609644659660665667669670675679680687688689690698699700708709755769770776778780786790797799800809866877879880887888897898899900908932943954965976979987989
```

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell - 40, 1020 Output

```
999..0|%{$s+=if(!($s-match$_)){"$_"}};$s
```

Output:

```
999998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888887886885884883882881880877876875874873872871870867866865864863862861860857856855854853852851850847846845844843842841840837836835834833832831830827826825824823822821820817816815814813812811810807806805804803802801800777776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555554553552551550544543542541540534533532531530524523522521520514513512511510504503502501500444443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333332331330322321320312311310302301300222221220211210201200111110101100
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 13 bytes (noncompeting), string length 1133

Pyke is newer than the challenge and thus is noncompetitive .

```
k~mV~oi{!o`*+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=k%7EmV%7Eoi%7B%21o%60%2a%2B)

```
              - o = 0
k~mV          - repeat 1000 times, i = ""
    ~oi{      -     str(o) in i
        !     -    not ^
         o`*  -   str(o++) * ^
            + -  i += ^
```

Comment: How long is the output?

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 36 bytes, 1020 output

```powershell
999..9|%{$s+=(,"$_")[$s-match$_]};$s
```

Output:

```powershell
999998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888887886885884883882881880877876875874873872871870867866865864863862861860857856855854853852851850847846845844843842841840837836835834833832831830827826825824823822821820817816815814813812811810807806805804803802801800777776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555554553552551550544543542541540534533532531530524523522521520514513512511510504503502501500444443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333332331330322321320312311310302301300222221220211210201200111110101100
```

### Alternative, 69 bytes, 1000 output

```powershell
999..9|%{$s+=("$_",($x="$_"[-1]))[2*($s-match$_)+($s+$x-match$_)]};$s
```

Output:

```powershell
9998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888788688588488388288188087787687587487387287187086786686586486386286186085785685585485385285185084784684584484384284184083783683583483383283183082782682582482382282182081781681581481381281181080780680580480380280180077767757747737727717707667657647637627617607567557547537527517507467457447437427417407367357347337327317307267257247237227217207167157147137127117107067057047037027017006665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555455355255155054454354254154053453353253153052452352252152051451351251151050450350250150044434424414404334324314304234224214204134124114104034024014003332331330322321320312311310302301300222122021121020120011101100
```

### Alternative, <s>82</s> 73 bytes, 999 output (minimum)

```powershell
for(;$z=9..0|?{"000$x"-notmatch-join"$x$_"[-3..-1]}|%{"$_"}){$x+=$z[0]}$x
```

This is simplified algorithm from [Generate the shortest De Bruijn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173125/80745) adapted for constants: alphabet=`9876543210` and length=`3`

Output:

```powershell
999899799699599499399299199098898798698598498398298198097897797697597497397297197096896796696596496396296196095895795695595495395295195094894794694594494394294194093893793693593493393293193092892792692592492392292192091891791691591491391291191090890790690590490390290190088878868858848838828818808778768758748738728718708678668658648638628618608578568558548538528518508478468458448438428418408378368358348338328318308278268258248238228218208178168158148138128118108078068058048038028018007776775774773772771770766765764763762761760756755754753752751750746745744743742741740736735734733732731730726725724723722721720716715714713712711710706705704703702701700666566466366266166065565465365265165064564464364264164063563463363263163062562462362262162061561461361261161060560460360260160055545535525515505445435425415405345335325315305245235225215205145135125115105045035025015004443442441440433432431430423422421420413412411410403402401400333233133032232132031231131030230130022212202112102012001110100
```

---

Test script:

```powershell
$f= {

#999..0|%{$s+=if(!($s-match$_)){"$_"}};$s

#999..9|%{$s+=("$_",($x="$_"[-1]))[2*($s-match$_)+($s+$x-match$_)]};$s-replace'1100','100'
#999..9|%{$s+=("$_",($x="$_"[-1]))[2*($s-match$_)+($s+$x-match$_)]};$s
#999..9|%{$s+=(,"$_")[$s-match$_]};$s-replace'(.)\1{3,}','$1$1$1'
#999..9|%{$s+=(,"$_")[$s-match$_]};$s-replace'(.)\1{3,}','$1$1$1'-replace'1100','0'
 for(;$z=9..0|?{"000$x"-notmatch-join"$x$_"[-3..-1]}|%{"$_"}){$x+=$z[0]}$x
#999..9|%{$s+=(,"$_")[$s-match$_]};$s

}

$s=&$f

$s
"Length:"
$s.Length
"count(###)!=1:"
$x=@{}
0..($s.Length-3)|%{$s.Substring($_,3)}|Group|%{
    $x[+$_.Name]=$_.Count
}
100..999|?{$x.$_-ne1}|%{,($_,+$x.$_)}|%{"$_"}
"count(##)!=10:"
$x=@{}
0..($s.Length-2)|%{$s.Substring($_,2)}|Group|%{
    $x[+$_.Name]=$_.Count
}
10..99|?{$x.$_-ne10}|%{,($_,+$x.$_)}|%{"$_"}
"count(#)!=100:"
$x=@{}
0..($s.Length-1)|%{$s.Substring($_,1)}|Group|%{
    $x[+$_.Name]=$_.Count
}
0..9|?{$x.$_-ne100}|%{,($_,+$x.$_)}|%{"$_"}
"All numbers:"
999-eq(1..999|?{$s-match$_}).Count
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) and [1109 characters](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOLm4vf4aXxmX6H1/yPTf8PAA)

```
₄FDNå_iNì
```

Outputs:

```
90990190089989088981980980880079979879078978878077977870970870770069969869769068968868768067967867767066966866760960860760660059959859759659058958858758658057957857757657056956856756656055955855755650950850750650550049949849749649549048948848748648548047947847747647547046946846746646546045945845745645545044944844744644540940840740640540440039939839739639539439038938838738638538438037937837737637537437036936836736636536436035935835735635535435034934834734634534434033933833733633533430930830730630530430330029929829729629529429329028928828728628528428328027927827727627527427327026926826726626526426326025925825725625525425325024924824724624524424324023923823723623523423323022922822722622522422320920820720620520420320220019919719619519419319219118918818718618518418318218017917817717617517417317217016916816716616516416316216015915815715615515415315215014914814714614514414314214013913813713613513413313213012912812712612512412312212011811711611511411311211110910810710610510410310210110099919089888079787770696867666059585756555049484746454440393837363534333029282726252423222018171615141312119876543210
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOLm4vf4aXxmX6H1/z/DwA) or [verify it contains all numbers below 1000](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOLm4vf4aXxmX6H1/yPddEBCtgcnptd5mevpJCWX5qXopBYopCZl5JaoaBkX6nzHwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
₄            # Push 1000
 F           # Loop N in the range [0,1000):
  D          #  Duplicate the top value on the stack
   Nå_i      #  If it does not contain N as substring yet:
       Nì    #   Prepend N to it
             # (Output implicitly after the loop)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>48</s> 44 bytes

Thanks to @primo for reminding me of `ereg`.

```
for($i=1e3;--$i;ereg($i,$s)?:$s.=$i);echo$s;
```

or

```
for($i=1e3;ereg(--$i,$s)?$i:$s.=$i;);echo$s;
```

output: 1020 chars. requires PHP<7

### PHP 7, 48 bytes:

`ereg` has been removed in PHP 7

```
for($i=1e3;--$i;strstr($s,"$i")?:$s.=$i);echo$s;
```

If the second argument to `strstr` (or `strpos` and other string searching functions) is not a string, it will be used as an ascii code, so `$i` needs a cast to string.

Comment: `ereg($i,$s)` for 4 (I would also include `<?` in the byte count).

Comment: @primo I just noticed that this challenge is older than PHP 7. double thanks. :)

Comment: `ereg` was removed, presumably, because the function name is too short, and/or didn't contain enough underscores. That `split` was also removed is especially brilliant.

Comment: `ereg` was removed because POSIX only contains a subset of PCRE´s possibilities;
and they probably didn´t want to maintain two different libraries.
I´ll ask should I ever meet Rasmus Lerdorf again.
`split` has been removed, but `join` remained (probably because it´s "only" an alias).
Sorry for pedantry; but I know people who cannot recognice irony.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 49 chars/bytes

I wasn't sure whether to do this as a function returning a string variable, or print out the result, so this just prints it to stdout. Using the regex matcher saved 2 bytes, using ternary operator instead of "if" saved another byte. The output string is 1133 characters.

```
a='';1000.times{a+=(a==~/.*$it.*/)?'':it};print a
```

Output:

```
01234567891011131415161718192021222425262728293032333536373839404344464748495054555758596065666869707677798087889099100102103104105106107108109110112114115116117118119120124125126127128129130132133134135136137138139140142143144145146147148149150152153154155156157158159160162163164165166167168169170172173174175176177178179180182183184185186187188189190193194195196197198199200203204205206207208209219220221223225226227228229230231235236237238239240243244245246247248249250253254255256257258259260263264265266267268269270273274275276277278279280283284285286287288289290294295296297298299300304305306307308309311329330332334336337338339340342346347348349350354355356357358359360364365366367368369370374375376377378379380384385386387388389390395396397398399400405406407408409422439440443445447448449450453457458459460465466467468469470475476477478479480485486487488489490496497498499500506507508509533549550554556558559560564568569570576577578579580586587588589590597598599600607608609644659660665667669670675679680687688689690698699700708709755769770776778780786790797799800809866877879880887888897898899900908932943954965976979987989
```

Answer (score 0):

## Game Maker Language, 1014 - String 1000

`show_message(909910010110210310410510610710810911121131141151161171181191201221231241251261271281291301321331341351361371381391401421431441451461471481491501521531541551561571581591601621631641651661671681691701721731741751761771781791801821831841851861871881891901921931941951961971981992002022032042052062072082092223224225226227228229230233234235236237238239240243244245246247248249250253254255256257258259260263264265266267268269270273274275276277278279280283284285286287288289290293294295296297298299300303304305306307308309333433533633733833934034434534634734834935035435535635735835936036436536636736836937037437537637737837938038438538638738838939039439539639739839940040440540640740840944454464474484494504554564574584594604654664674684694704754764774784794804854864874884894904954964974984995005055065075085095556557558559560566567568569570576577578579580586587588589590596597598599600606607608609666766866967067767867968068768868969069769869970070770870977787797807887897907987998008088098889890899900)`

Also:

### Ruby, 1003 - String 1000

`p'909910010110210310410510610710810911121131141151161171181191201221231241251261271281291301321331341351361371381391401421431441451461471481491501521531541551561571581591601621631641651661671681691701721731741751761771781791801821831841851861871881891901921931941951961971981992002022032042052062072082092223224225226227228229230233234235236237238239240243244245246247248249250253254255256257258259260263264265266267268269270273274275276277278279280283284285286287288289290293294295296297298299300303304305306307308309333433533633733833934034434534634734834935035435535635735835936036436536636736836937037437537637737837938038438538638738838939039439539639739839940040440540640740840944454464474484494504554564574584594604654664674684694704754764774784794804854864874884894904954964974984995005055065075085095556557558559560566567568569570576577578579580586587588589590596597598599600606607608609666766866967067767867968068768868969069769869970070770870977787797807887897907987998008088098889890899900'`