# Generate a sequence with unique subsequences

Tags: code-challenge

The string `2123132133` has the property that no subsequence of length 3 is the same as any other subsequence of length 3.

Your task is to build a program that will output as long of a string as possible that satisfies this property for sequences of length 9 with the characters from `1` to `9`.

The source code of your program may not be longer than 16 kilobytes (16,384 bytes). The program that wins is the one that outputs the longest sequence of digits from `1` to `9` such that no subsequence of 9 digits is the same.

Comment: You may want to tighten up the output requirements so that the *only* output is the sequence such that no subsequence is the same. Otherwise, as it currently reads, it may be possible to submit a `while(1){putchar('1'+rand()%9);}` submission that just spews random digits forever and it could be argued that its output *will* contain (given enough time) "the longest sequence of digits from 1 to 9 such that no subsequence of 9 digits is the same." That would be a dick move, for sure, but easily prevented. Cheers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "outputs the longest sequence of digits" implies that the entire sequence of digits that a program outputs must satisfy the subsequence requirement. Thanks for your concern, though.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/13088/194)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm starting with here is a [De Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).  Stealing some reference code on the topic, here is my submission:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def de_bruijn(k, n):
    """ De Bruijn sequence for alphabet size k and subsequences of length n. """
    a = [0] * k * n
    sequence = []
    def db(t, p):
        if t > n:
            if n % p == 0:
                for j in range(1, p + 1):
                    sequence.append(a[j])
        else:
            a[t] = a[t - p]
            db(t + 1, p)
            for j in range(a[t - p] + 1, k):
                a[t] = j
                db(t + 1, t)
    db(1, 1)
    return sequence

seq = de_bruijn(9, 9) # cyclic
seq = seq + seq[:8]   # extended to max 
print(''.join(map(lambda n: chr(49+n), seq)))
```

After running for ten minutes, the output is a 387,420,497 digit sequence.  This is 9^9 + 8 digits, as expected.  (Thank you @PeterTaylor for the +8 tip on the cyclic output.)

Comment: Almost. De Bruijn sequences are cyclic, so you can copy the first 8 characters to the end to get a maximum-length non-cyclic string.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that theorem existed. Looks like your answer will be the accepted one.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterTaylor.  That makes sense.  I've extended the sequence.