# Generate the shortest De Bruijn

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

A De Bruijn sequence is interesting: It is the shortest, cyclic sequence that contains all possible sequences of a given alphabet of a given length.  For example, if we were considering the alphabet A,B,C and a length of 3, a possible output is:

```
AAABBBCCCABCACCBBAACBCBABAC
```

You will notice that every possible 3-character sequence using the letters `A`, `B`, and `C` are in there.

Your challenge is to generate a De Bruijn sequence in as few characters as possible.  Your function should take two parameters, an integer representing the length of the sequences, and a list containing the alphabet.  Your output should be the sequence in list form.

You may assume that every item in the alphabet is distinct.

An example generator can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence)

[Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) apply

Comment: Can the integer representing the length of the sequences be larger than the number of unique letters?

Comment: Yes.  A binary sequence of length 4 would be 0000111101100101

Comment: "Your challenge is to generate a De Bruijn sequence in as few characters as possible" - Does this mean "code golf" or "get the shortest possible De Bruijn sequence length"?

Comment: Both.  To qualify, your program must output the shortest sequence possible, but to win, your program must be the shortest.

Comment: "A binary sequence of length 4 would be 0000111101100101" => 0100 1000 and 1010 are missing here... unless sequences can be read backwards? It's not told in the rules :)

Comment: I know it's not allowed, but I would just like to point out that Mathematica has a built-in for this: `DeBruijnSequence[#,#2]&` (albeit not in the core language but the *Combinatorica* package).

Comment: I'm sure this has been posted before, but maybe it was closed as a duplicate of [this very similar question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/13088/194) and deleted.

Comment: @xem: usually De Bruijn sequences include wraparound, which is where those missing sequences appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, 31 bytes

This is the direct conversion of the algorithm used in my [CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42730/31414). Tips for golfing welcome!

```
Mu?G}H+GG+G>Hefq<HT>G-lGTUH^GHk
```

This code defines a function `g` which takes two arguments, the string of list of characters and the number.

Example usage:

```
Mu?G}H+GG+G>Hefq<HT>G-lGTUH^GHkg"ABC"3
```

Output:

```
AAABAACABBABCACBACCBBBCBCCC
```

Code expansion:

```
M                 # def g(G,H):
 u                #   return reduce(lambda G, H:
  ?G              #     (G if
    }H            #       (H in
      +GG         #          add(G,G)) else
    +G            #       add(G,
      >H          #         slice_end(H,
        e         #           last_element(
         f        #             Pfilter(lambda T:
          q       #               equal(
           <HT    #                 slice_start(H,T),
           >G     #                 slice_end(G,
             -lGT #                   minus(Plen(G),T))),
          UH      #               urange(H)))))),
  ^GH             #     cartesian_product(G,H),
  k               #     "")
```

[Try it here](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>52 49</s> 48 bytes

This is surprisingly long. This can be golfed a lot, taking in tips from the Pyth translation.

```
q~a*{m*:s}*{:H\:G_+\#)GGHH,,{_H<G,@-G>=},W=>+?}*
```

The input goes like

```
3 "ABC"
```

i.e. - String of list of characters and the length.

and output is the De Bruijn string

```
AAABAACABBABCACBACCBBBCBCCC
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: Gosh CJam should be banned, it is not just made for one golfing task but it seems for every possible golfing task...

Comment: @flawr you should wait for a Pyth answer then :P

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>52</s> 49 bytes

Here is a different approach in CJam:

```
l~:N;:L,(:Ma{_N*N<0{;)_!}g(+_0a=!}g]{,N\%!},:~Lf=
```

Takes input like this:

```
"ABC" 3
```

and produces a Lyndon work like

```
CCCBCCACBBCBACABCAABBBABAAA
```

[Try it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

This makes use of [the relation with Lyndon words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word). It generates all Lyndon words of length *n* in lexicographic order (as outlined in that Wikipedia article), then drops those whose length doesn't divide *n*. This already yields the De Bruijn sequence, but since I'm generating the Lyndon words as strings of digits, I also need to replace those with the corresponding letters at the end.

For golfing reasons, I consider the later letters in the alphabet to have lower lexicographic order.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ṁL*¥Œ!;`wⱮẠɗƇṗḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//4bmBTCrCpcWSITtgd@KxruG6oMmXxofhuZfhuKL/w6f//yIxMCL/Mw)

Pretty slow, uses a brute force approach with around an \$O(n \times m \times (n \times m)!)\$ complexity, where \$n\$ is the integer input and \$m\$ is the length of the string. Times out if both \$n\$ and \$m\$ are greater than 3 on TIO

### How it works

The length of the De Bruijn sequence will always be \$m^n\$ and each symbol in the provided alphabet will occur the same number of times, \$m^{n-1}\$. Therefore, we generate the string with that many symbols, then filter its permutations to find valid De Bruijn sequences.

```
ṁL*¥Œ!ẋ2wⱮẠʋƇṗḢ - Main link. Takes an alphabet A on the left and n on the right
   ¥            - Last 2 links as a dyad f(A, n):
 L              -   Length of A
  *             -   Raised to the power n
ṁ               - Mold A to that length
    Œ!          - All permutations
             ṗ  - Powerset; Get all length n combinations of A. Call that C
           ʋƇ   - Filter the permutations P on the following dyad g(P, C):
      ẋ2        -   Repeat P twice
         Ɱ      -   For each element E in C:
        w       -     Is it a sublist of P?
          Ạ     -   Is this true for all elements of C?
              Ḣ - Take the first one
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 143

Using Lyndon words, like Martin's aswer, just 3 times long...

```js
F=(a,n)=>{
  for(w=[-a[l='length']],r='';w[0];)
  {
    n%w[l]||w.map(x=>r+=a[~x]);
    for(;w.push(...w)<=n;);
    for(w[l]=n;!~(z=w.pop()););
    w.push(z+1)
  }
  return r
}
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
console.log(F("ABC",3),F("10",4))
```

*Output*

```
CCCBCCACBBCBACABCAABBBABAAA 0000100110101111
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 114 bytes

I'm not really sure how to golf it more, due to my approach.

```python
def f(a,n):
 s=a[-1]*n
 while 1:
    for c in a:
     if((s+c)[len(s+c)-n:]in s)<1:s+=c;break
    else:break
 print s[:1-n]
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/EgeQ/1)

**Ungolfed:**

This code is a trivial modification from [my solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101991/34718) to more recent challenge.

```python
def f(a,n):
    s=a[-1]*n
    while 1:
        for c in a:
            p=s+c
            if p[len(p)-n:]in s:
                continue
            else:
                s=p
                break
        else:
            break
    print s[:1-n]
```

The only reason `[:1-n]` is needed is because the sequence includes the wrap-around.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>164</s> 96 bytes

*-68 bytes with -match `O($n*2^n)` instead recursive generator `O(n*log(n))`*

```powershell
param($s,$n)for(;$z=$s|% t*y|?{"$($s[-1])"*($n-1)+$x-notmatch-join"$x$_"[-$n..-1]}){$x+=$z[0]}$x
```

Ungolfed & test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($s,$n)                    # $s is a alphabet, $n is a subsequence length
for(;                           # repeat until...
    $z=$s|% t*y|?{              # at least a character from the alphabet returns $true for expression:
        "$($s[-1])"*($n-1)+$x-notmatch  # the old sequence that follows two characters (the last letter from the alphabet) not contains
        -join"$x$_"[-$n..-1]    # n last characters from the new sequence
}){
    $x+=$z[0]                   # replace old sequence with new sequence
}
$x                              # return the sequence

}

@(
    ,("ABC",  2, "AABACBBCC")
    ,("ABC",  3, "AAABAACABBABCACBACCBBBCBCCC")
    ,("ABC",  4, "AAAABAAACAABBAABCAACBAACCABABACABBBABBCABCBABCCACACBBACBCACCBACCCBBBBCBBCCBCBCCCC")
    ,("ABC",  5, "AAAAABAAAACAAABBAAABCAAACBAAACCAABABAABACAABBBAABBCAABCBAABCCAACABAACACAACBBAACBCAACCBAACCCABABBABABCABACBABACCABBACABBBBABBBCABBCBABBCCABCACABCBBABCBCABCCBABCCCACACBACACCACBBBACBBCACBCBACBCCACCBBACCBCACCCBACCCCBBBBBCBBBCCBBCBCBBCCCBCBCCBCCCCC")
    ,("ABC",  6, "AAAAAABAAAAACAAAABBAAAABCAAAACBAAAACCAAABABAAABACAAABBBAAABBCAAABCBAAABCCAAACABAAACACAAACBBAAACBCAAACCBAAACCCAABAABAACAABABBAABABCAABACBAABACCAABBABAABBACAABBBBAABBBCAABBCBAABBCCAABCABAABCACAABCBBAABCBCAABCCBAABCCCAACAACABBAACABCAACACBAACACCAACBABAACBACAACBBBAACBBCAACBCBAACBCCAACCABAACCACAACCBBAACCBCAACCCBAACCCCABABABACABABBBABABBCABABCBABABCCABACACABACBBABACBCABACCBABACCCABBABBABCABBACBABBACCABBBACABBBBBABBBBCABBBCBABBBCCABBCACABBCBBABBCBCABBCCBABBCCCABCABCACBABCACCABCBACABCBBBABCBBCABCBCBABCBCCABCCACABCCBBABCCBCABCCCBABCCCCACACACBBACACBCACACCBACACCCACBACBACCACBBBBACBBBCACBBCBACBBCCACBCBBACBCBCACBCCBACBCCCACCACCBBBACCBBCACCBCBACCBCCACCCBBACCCBCACCCCBACCCCCBBBBBBCBBBBCCBBBCBCBBBCCCBBCBBCBCCBBCCBCBBCCCCBCBCBCCCBCCBCCCCCC")
    ,("01",   3, "00010111")
    ,("01",   4, "0000100110101111")
    ,("abcd", 2, "aabacadbbcbdccdd")
    ,("0123456789", 3, "0001002003004005006007008009011012013014015016017018019021022023024025026027028029031032033034035036037038039041042043044045046047048049051052053054055056057058059061062063064065066067068069071072073074075076077078079081082083084085086087088089091092093094095096097098099111211311411511611711811912212312412512612712812913213313413513613713813914214314414514614714814915215315415515615715815916216316416516616716816917217317417517617717817918218318418518618718818919219319419519619719819922232242252262272282292332342352362372382392432442452462472482492532542552562572582592632642652662672682692732742752762772782792832842852862872882892932942952962972982993334335336337338339344345346347348349354355356357358359364365366367368369374375376377378379384385386387388389394395396397398399444544644744844945545645745845946546646746846947547647747847948548648748848949549649749849955565575585595665675685695765775785795865875885895965975985996667668669677678679687688689697698699777877978878979879988898999")
    ,("9876543210", 3, "9998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888788688588488388288188087787687587487387287187086786686586486386286186085785685585485385285185084784684584484384284184083783683583483383283183082782682582482382282182081781681581481381281181080780680580480380280180077767757747737727717707667657647637627617607567557547537527517507467457447437427417407367357347337327317307267257247237227217207167157147137127117107067057047037027017006665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555455355255155054454354254154053453353253153052452352252152051451351251151050450350250150044434424414404334324314304234224214204134124114104034024014003332331330322321320312311310302301300222122021121020120011101000")
) |% {
    $s,$n,$e = $_
    $r = &$f $s $n
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: AABACBBCC
True: AAABAACABBABCACBACCBBBCBCCC
True: AAAABAAACAABBAABCAACBAACCABABACABBBABBCABCBABCCACACBBACBCACCBACCCBBBBCBBCCBCBCCCC
True: AAAAABAAAACAAABBAAABCAAACBAAACCAABABAABACAABBBAABBCAABCBAABCCAACABAACACAACBBAACBCAACCBAACCCABABBABABCABACBABACCABBACABBBBABBBCABBCBABBCCABCACABCBBABCBCABCCBABCCCACACBACACCACBBBACBBCACBCBACBCCACCBBACCBCACCCBACCCCBBBBBCBBBCCBBCBCBBCCCBCBCCBCCCCC
True: AAAAAABAAAAACAAAABBAAAABCAAAACBAAAACCAAABABAAABACAAABBBAAABBCAAABCBAAABCCAAACABAAACACAAACBBAAACBCAAACCBAAACCCAABAABAACAABABBAABABCAABACBAABACCAABBABAABBACAABBBBAABBBCAABBCBAABBCCAABCABAABCACAABCBBAABCBCAABCCBAABCCCAACAACABBAACABCAACACBAACACCAACBABAACBACAACBBBAACBBCAACBCBAACBCCAACCABAACCACAACCBBAACCBCAACCCBAACCCCABABABACABABBBABABBCABABCBABABCCABACACABACBBABACBCABACCBABACCCABBABBABCABBACBABBACCABBBACABBBBBABBBBCABBBCBABBBCCABBCACABBCBBABBCBCABBCCBABBCCCABCABCACBABCACCABCBACABCBBBABCBBCABCBCBABCBCCABCCACABCCBBABCCBCABCCCBABCCCCACACACBBACACBCACACCBACACCCACBACBACCACBBBBACBBBCACBBCBACBBCCACBCBBACBCBCACBCCBACBCCCACCACCBBBACCBBCACCBCBACCBCCACCCBBACCCBCACCCCBACCCCCBBBBBBCBBBBCCBBBCBCBBBCCCBBCBBCBCCBBCCBCBBCCCCBCBCBCCCBCCBCCCCCC
True: 00010111
True: 0000100110101111
True: aabacadbbcbdccdd
True: 0001002003004005006007008009011012013014015016017018019021022023024025026027028029031032033034035036037038039041042043044045046047048049051052053054055056057058059061062063064065066067068069071072073074075076077078079081082083084085086087088089091092093094095096097098099111211311411511611711811912212312412512612712812913213313413513613713813914214314414514614714814915215315415515615715815916216316416516616716816917217317417517617717817918218318418518618718818919219319419519619719819922232242252262272282292332342352362372382392432442452462472482492532542552562572582592632642652662672682692732742752762772782792832842852862872882892932942952962972982993334335336337338339344345346347348349354355356357358359364365366367368369374375376377378379384385386387388389394395396397398399444544644744844945545645745845946546646746846947547647747847948548648748848949549649749849955565575585595665675685695765775785795865875885895965975985996667668669677678679687688689697698699777877978878979879988898999
True: 9998997996995994993992991990988987986985984983982981980978977976975974973972971970968967966965964963962961960958957956955954953952951950948947946945944943942941940938937936935934933932931930928927926925924923922921920918917916915914913912911910908907906905904903902901900888788688588488388288188087787687587487387287187086786686586486386286186085785685585485385285185084784684584484384284184083783683583483383283183082782682582482382282182081781681581481381281181080780680580480380280180077767757747737727717707667657647637627617607567557547537527517507467457447437427417407367357347337327317307267257247237227217207167157147137127117107067057047037027017006665664663662661660655654653652651650645644643642641640635634633632631630625624623622621620615614613612611610605604603602601600555455355255155054454354254154053453353253153052452352252152051451351251151050450350250150044434424414404334324314304234224214204134124114104034024014003332331330322321320312311310302301300222122021121020120011101000
```

---

See also: [One Ring to rule them all. One String to contain them all](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172936/80745)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,n:(a[:n]in a[1:])*a[n:]or max((f(c+a,n)for c in{*a}),key=len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcq7DkAwFADQ3Vd0ay8dCFMTAz6j6XA9Gg2uRgxEfHt1sp4cf5/zTmUItl5x60dkKEkJ1IqMI4a6UAZS1KTMfrANLyGsGLKYwEYYmKMnxRfkMt31OhEEfzg6Y@JN23FZAiS/FDmXFUD4AA)