# Output diagonal positions of me squared

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix

Given a number `n`, Output an ordered list of 1-based indices falling on either of the diagonals of an `n*n` square matrix.

### Example:

For an input of `3`:

The square shall be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Now we select all the indices represented by `\`, `/` or `X` (`#` or non-diagonal positions are rejected)

```
\ # /
# X #
/ # \
```

The output shall be:

```
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

## Test cases:

```
1=>[1]
2=>[1,2,3,4]
3=>[1,3,5,7,9]
4=>[1,4,6,7,10,11,13,16]
5=>[1,5,7,9,13,17,19,21,25]
```

There will be no accepted answer. I want to know the shortest code for each language.

Comment: The question is asking for the (1-indexed) indices of the \, / and X characters in the images. Not a bad question per se, but lacks explanation.

Comment: If you are willing to provide a brief and clear explanation of what you want, We will probably reopen this, as it is not a bad challenge. As of now, it is just very unclear

Comment: I've voted to reopen, though you might also want to move the ascii images out of the examples area to avoid confusion. At first I wasn't sure if I had to produce those as well (but I understand the wanted output is only the list of indices)

Comment: @Ruud: And how will do people understand what are the asked positions if they don't see the images?

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't show them at all, just that you put them (or just two or three of them) with the explanation of the challenge, rather than the example inputs and outputs.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: @sergiol Is 0-indexing allowed? My previous question stands ^

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Does the order matter? Yes. Is 0-indexing allowed? No. Because it is how I specified the question in the examples.

Comment: FWIW I think having the order be irrelevant might make for more interesting golfs...

Comment: Would a dash-separated string be a valid output? e.g. `"1-3-5-7-9"`

Comment: @Arnauld: yes .

Comment: @ThePirateBay: If you don't publish the derived challenge, I will publish it myself!

Answer (score 10):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

```matlab
@(n)find((I=eye(n))+flip(I))
```

Anonymous function that inputs a number and outputs a column vector of numbers.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI08zLTMvRUPD0za1MhXI09ROy8ks0PDU1PyfpmGs@R8A)

Comment: So simple... :)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

Outputs a dash-separated list of integers as a string.

```js
f=(n,k=n*n)=>--k?f(n,k)+(k%~-n&&k%-~n?'':~k):'1'
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
f = (n, k = n * n) => // given n and starting with k = n²
  --k ?               // decrement k; if it does not equal zero:
    f(n, k) + (       //   return the result of a recursive call followed by:
      k % ~-n &&      //     if both k % (n - 1) and
      k % -~n ?       //             k % (n + 1) are non-zero:
        ''            //       an empty string
      :               //     else:
        ~k            //       -(k + 1) (instantly coerced to a string)
    )                 //   end of iteration
  :                   // else:
    '1'               //   return '1' and stop recursion
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,k=n*n)=>--k?f(n,k)+(k%~-n&&k%-~n?'':~k):'1'

;[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(n => console.log(n, '->', f(n)))
```

Comment: Nice workaround, using the signs as separators. Could you use bitwsie `&` to save a byte?

Comment: @Shaggy No, that wouldn't work. For instance: `4%3` and `4%5` have no 1-bit in common, but both are non-zero.

Comment: Yup, just tested it with `n=5` and spotted that it wouldn't work.

Comment: `k%~-n&&k%-~n` should work. nice trick with the separator!

Comment: @Titus Not that it really matters when it comes to golfing but ... yeah, that might be _slightly_ more readable. :-) (updated)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> <s>35</s> <s>34</s>  38 bytes

3 bytes saved when I remembered about the existence of the `which` function...
, 1 byte saved thanks to @Rift

```r
d=diag(n<-scan());which(d|d[n:1,])
```

+4 bytes for the argument `ec=T` when called as a full program by `source()`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8U2JTMxXSPPRrc4OTFPQ1PTujwjMzlDI6UmJTrPylAnVvO/6X8A)

Explanation:

```r
n<-scan()            # take input
d=diag(n);           # create an identity matrix (ones on diagonal, zeros elsewhere)
d|d[n:1,]            # coerce d to logical and combine (OR) with a flipped version
which([d|d[n:1,]])   # Find indices for T values in the logical expression above
```

Comment: -1 byte `d=diag(n<-scan());which(d|d[n:1,])`

Comment: When running this as a full program (`source`) this doesn't print anything. You have to call `cat`. See [this post on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-should-a-full-program-in-r-be-invoked/13744#13744).

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Fair enough! I had always worked on the basis that it gives valid output on TIO, never really considered the requirements of being a "full program".

Comment: Though I'm not planning on going back and editing all my old answers to fix this!

Comment: It is a bit vague, because of the console environment of R and code snippets being the main way of using it. Feel free to share insights on that meta thread I linked. It hasn't received all that much input.

Comment: [37 bytes as a function](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPJ8U2JTMxXSNPU7M8IzM5QyOlJiU6z8pQJ1bzf5qGqeZ/AA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
⁼þ`+Ṛ$ẎT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R457D@xK0H@6cpfJwV1/I////TQE)

Uses Luis Mendo's algorithm on his MATL answer.

Comment: Mhm, I am quite surprised you didn't use `ŒD`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `ŒD` does something completely different from X of a specific size.

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

This works in MATLAB too by the way. No sneaky Octave specific functionality :)

```matlab
@(x)unique([x:x-1:x^2-1;1:x+1:x*x+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzNC@zsDRVI7rCqkLX0KoizkjX0BpIawOxFpCM1fyfpmGm@R8A)

#### Explanation:

Instead of creating a square matrix, and find the two diagonals, I figured I rather calculate the diagonals directly instead. This was **17** bytes shorter! =)

```matlab
@(x)                                   % Anonymous function that takes 'x' as input
    unique(...                   ...)  % unique gives the unique elements, sorted
           [x:x-1:x^2-1                % The anti-diagonal (is that the correct word?)
                       ;               % New row
                        1:x+1:x*x+1])  % The regular diagonal
```

This is what it looks like, without `unique`:

```matlab
ans =    
    6   11   16   21   26   31
    1    8   15   22   29   36
```

<sub>Yes, I should probably have flipped the order of the diagonals to make it more human-friendly.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
XytP+f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6KyJEA77f9/YwA)

#### Explanation

Same approach as my Octave answer.

Consider input `3` as an example.

```
Xy   % Implicit input. Identity matrix of that size
     % STACK: [1 0 0;
               0 1 0;
               0 0 1]
t    % Duplicate
     % STACK: [1 0 0
               0 1 0
               0 0 1],
              [1 0 0
               0 1 0
               0 0 1]
P    % Flip vertically
     % STACK: [1 0 0
               0 1 0
               0 0 1],
              [0 0 1
               0 1 0
               1 0 0]
+    % Add
     % STACK: [1 0 1
               0 2 0
               1 0 1]
f    % Linear indices of nonzero entries. Implicit display  
     % STACK:[1; 3; 5; 7; 9]
```

Linear indexing is [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), 1-based. For more information see length-12 snippet [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76535/36398).

Comment: What is "transpose" supposed to mean?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Sorry, my bad. `t` is duplicate, not transpose. Also, I've added a worked out example

Comment: Amazing! It would take me two loops if I want to accomplish this.

Comment: @LuisMendo I suspected so, because transposing an identity matrix makes no sense...hmm, I managed to save a byte with your algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```python
lambda n:[i+1for i in range(n*n)if i%-~n<1or i%~-n<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpT2zAtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNPK08zM00hU1W3Ls/GECSnWqcLZMX@hys01DHSMdYx0TG1UigoyswrUcjUUUjTyNT8DwA)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
Union@Flatten@Table[{i,#+1-i}+i#-#,{i,#}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/NC8zP8/BLSexpCQ1zyEkMSknNbo6U0dZ21A3s1Y7U1lXWQfErY1V@x9QlJlXouCQFm0YywVnGyGxjZHYJkhs09j//wE)

@KellyLowder golfed it down to..

## Mathematica, 37 bytes

```
##&@@@Table[{i-#,1-i}+i#,{i,#}]⋃{}&
```

and @alephalpha threw away the table!

## Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
Union@@Range[{1,#},#^2,{#+1,#-1}]&
```

Comment: `##&@@@Table[{i-#,1-i}+i#,{i,#}]⋃{}&` is 5 bytes shorter

Comment: `Union@@Range[{1,#},#^2,{#+1,#-1}]&`

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, <s>68</s> 54 bytes

*Thanks to @Stewie Griffin for saving 14 bytes!*

```
@(x)unique([diag(m=reshape(1:x^2,x,x)),diag(flip(m))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzNC@zsDRVIzolMzFdI9e2KLU4I7EgVcPQqiLOSKdCp0JTUwcslZaTWaCRq6kZq/k/TcNY8z8A)

## MATLAB, 68 bytes

```
x=input('');m=reshape([1:x*x],x,x);unique([diag(m) diag(flipud(m))])
```

**Explanation:**

```
@(x)                               % Anonymous function
m=reshape([1:x*x],x,x);            % Create a vector from 1 to x^2 and
                                   % reshape it into an x*x matrix.
diag(m)                            % Find the values on the diagonal.
diag(flip(m))                      % Flip the matrix upside down and
                                   % find the values on the diagonal.
unique([])                         % Place the values from both diagonals
                                   % into a vector and remove duplicates.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 41 bytes

```python
n=>[i+1for i:0..n*n if!(i%-~n)or!(i%~-n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/P1i46U9swLb9IIdPKQE8vTytPITNNUSNTVbcuTzO/CMSq083TjP0PURJtqGOkY6xjomMaW82lAAQFRZl5JRqZOgppGpmamly1/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
U:GeGXytPY|*Xz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9TKPdU9orIkILJGK6Lq/39TAA)

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6KyJEA77f9/YwA)

Comment: Wow! Please post it, I'll eventually delete mine

Comment: I will post it if you are not going to incorporate it into your answer; but no need to delete yours

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>65</s> 58 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to Titus!*

```c
f(n,i){for(i=0;i<n*n;i++)i%-~n&&i%~-n||printf("%d ",i+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoMwEETv@YolENlUBXvoKdp/KbEpe@gqqfai8dfTJSC9zMzOsM@3L@9zDsgN2S1MEWnoHPV8YUd1bcm0B1cVmaPlfZ8j8RJQmxF0Q/XVupSlgfeDGL8TjRY2BVAwUhMM0DmxHm5igiszwMkJaORluJ@0Mgb853ldPqh1uZISic9ljSxUlfIP)

Comment: `i%-~n&&i%~-n||printf("%d ",i+1)` (-7 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>73</s> 63 bytes

*old version*

```
n=>[...Array(y=n*n).keys(),y].filter(x=>(--x/n|0)==x%n||(x/n|0)==n-x%n-1)
```

*Saved 10 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```
n=>[...Array(n*n)].map((_,y)=>y+1).filter(x=>!(--x%-~n&&x%~-n))
```

First time golfing! here's hoping I didn't mess up too badly.

```js
let f=n=>[...Array(n*n)].map((_,y)=>y+1).filter(x=>!(--x%-~n&&x%~-n));
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(n=>console.log(f(n)))
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) A similar solution to the one I was working on (only mine is 0-indexed). You might be able to save some bytes by using the following in your `filter` function: `!(--x%(n+1)&&x%(n-1))` and by creating your array like so: `[...Array(n*n+1).keys()]`

Comment: @Shaggy Thank you! I'll try to improve the answer with your suggestion as soon as I get home from work!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way: "*it's a bit shorter than creating a `[1...n*n]` range with `Array(n*n).fill().map((x,i)=>i+1)`*" - `[...Array(n*n)].map((_,y)=>y+1)` is a shorter way of doing that, for future reference.

Comment: Did a bit more with it and ended up with this for 56 bytes: `n=>[...Array(n*n+1).keys()].filter(x=>!(--x%-~n&&x%~-n))`

Comment: @Shaggy I tried your last version but it would output an extra zero for f(1) and f(2), it works with a [1...n*n] range though so I used the way you showed me in the previous comment. Or maybe I messed up someway?

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>97</strike> 83 bytes

```cs
f=>{var s="[";for(int i=0;i<n*n-1;)s+=i%-~n<1|i++%~-n<1?i+",":"";return s+n*n+"]";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BagIxEIbP7lMMASHbuKKHXsxGD4WeKkh78CA9hGy2DOgEMlmh6PrqaVboaYafb@b7HTcuRJ8HRvqBr19O/qIrd7bMcIBbNeNkEzq4Buxgb5FkPaUzpAQEBspcHmxkL98CcTj75ae33QeSl3WtC/g@kGsLteAUi2ILfQnKYe7N9na1EdiIk9B9iHL6iWalsaUXata6ZmVw3jyoXd9RqfmjKdsOlViIjRA6@jREAlaFVuJb6DFPwv8ex4jJy8km6VllrMb8mv8A)

The change here is based on the shift between numbers to find. The two shifts starting at 0 are `n-1` and `n+1`, so if `n=5`, the numbers for `n-1` would be `0,4,8,12,16,20` and for `n+1` would be `0,6,12,18,24`. Combining these and giving 1-indexing (instead of 0-indexing) gives `1,5,7,9,13,17,19,21,25`. The offset from `n` is achieved using bitwise negation (bitwise complement operation), where `~-n==n-1` and `-~n==n+1`.

#### Old Version

```cs
f=>{var s="[";for(int i=0;i<n*n-1;i++)s+=(i/n!=i%n&&n-1-i/n!=i%n?"":i+1+",");return s+$"{n*n}]";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BSwMxEIXP3V8xBi1J023twYtp2oPgSaHYQw/iIaRZGagTyGQLsuxvj1mhp@F9vDfveW59TKH0jPQNx1/O4cc0/uKY4QBDM@PsMnq4RjzDu0OSaqIzpAwEFupdHVziIF8icbyE1Udw5zekIJUy1fjak99W15JzqhU76CqowdLZ3XB1CdiKT2G6mOT0E@2jwS0tqN0Y1FqxthLXdGfxgebzStub2gvxjHqjxVIok0LuEwHrezHU8PglzFim@tuqU8Ic5NQt6X/Y2IzlqfwB)

This approach uses the column and row indices for determining if the numbers are on the diagonals. `i/n` gives the row index, and `i%n` gives the column index.

#### Returning Only The Number Array

If constructing only the number array is deemed to count towards the byte cost, then the following could be done, based on Dennis.Verweij's suggestion (`using System.Linq;` adds an extra 18 bytes):

[C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 66+18=84 bytes

```cs
x=>Enumerable.Range(1,x*x).Where(v=>~-v%~-x<1|~-v%-~x<1).ToArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5Pa8IwHD0vnyIUhUTagAdPtYUh8yB6mYKH0kOMP7uAJjO/tFS69qvXbDDw8ODxeP8UJso6GGvUpqL7B3q4ia0295S8SilRV4lIvzuCXnqt6Lo2aqmNjwOKMr9kY5vlH6a@gZOnK4hPaSpg87idtVwcv8ABa7J8SJrpkLTL@c8vS4bAuDjYd@fkg/Ex/W9vrD7TndSGoXfhRlFS6SrkHXlbWYM2DByd9hCeAptERbf/s4mNDZEojuILW3DelxFPSU/68Qk)

Comment: you can reduce the code by getting rid of the extra `&`. The extra `&` is there only to break the comparison if the first input is false [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator)

Comment: in fact you can have 92 bytes by using Linq [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7BisIwFDybrwhFIdltAwVvtYVlWQ@iFxU8iIcYn92ATXbz0lKp/fYaBcHDDMwww4zCRFkHQ43alHRzRQ@VWGrzn5F3KyPqIhHpX0fQS68VnddGzbTxccD@UJzzoc2LH1NX4OTxAmItTQksjduPlovdLzhgTV6wJkn5hLWBZ@ntpT4fiout/XJOXhkfstdKY/WJrqQ2DL0Ld/YHKl2JvCOjb2vQhqGd0x7CY2DjqNs8U2JhQyOKo/jMppz3Ec9IT/rhDg "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Dennis.Verweij Neat, I wasn't sure how much I could shift to the header or footer in TIO. I'll have a play around with mine.

Comment: you have to remember to include 18 bytes for the reference to linq (using System.Linq;) which is unfortunate, but how it works :S

Comment: Ah, ok. But that isn't necessary for `using System;`? (I assume wrapping it in a `namespace System.Linq` isn't valid?)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

<sup>([Here is the initial version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/140327/1).)</sup>

```
hMf|<%ThQ1<%TtQ1U*
```

**[Test Suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hMf%7C%3C%25ThQ1%3C%25TtQ1U%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 18 bytes

```
hMf>1*%ThQ%T|tQ1U*
```

**[Test Suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hMf%3E1%2a%25ThQ%25T%7CtQ1U%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 56 + 1 (-n) = 57 bytes

```perl
!(($_+1+$_/$,)%$,&&$_%($,+1))&&say++$_ for 0..($,=$_)**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEADArxisoq6aBh57Qm@QDgVBqGiXPt/mdaYe7Y5Ek5SQMCCkGYziYISAxCUYDEoJ0fcXx7GzNOadG75CUlovRPEr9blK7mS36HzwZPMP)

Comment: Shouldn't ` -n` be +3?

Comment: No.  The assumed command line is `perl -e`.  The command line for this example would be `perl -ne`.  That's a difference of +1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 71 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=0;i<n*n;i++)if(i%-~n<1||i%~-n<1)System.out.println(i+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU6xTsMwFNz7FW@pZBPHaoAuuGVhYmDqWHUwrlO9kDxH8UsRStNfD6YKTAxP73R3urvKnm0eWk/V8WNq@/caHbjaxghvFgmGBcDMRrac3jngEZqkiR13SKf9AWx3ivJmBahSnu4Za1325BgD6Vfil0Cxb3wH5Xai/HkoQyeQGHC7MrihOzKYZRJLgcv8SpvicsHlNU9A7r4i@0aHnnWb6rgmgVkhzTiZW99f0hOQ/4QE94dhpaBQcK/gQcGjgvX4uy75tXXOtyxQmpn6p2LWxsXPjdM3)

Port of [scottinet's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140339/16236).

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 16 bytes

Can't seem to do better than this but I'm sure it's possible. Had to sacrifice 2 bytes for the unnecessary requirement that we use 1-indexing.

```
²õ f@´XvUÉ ªXvUÄ
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=svUgZkC0WHZVySCqWHZVxA==&input=NQo=)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 32 bytes

```
@(n)find((m=abs(--n:-2:-n))==m')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPMy0zL0VDI9c2MalYQ1c3z0rXyEo3T1PT1jZXXfN/Yl6xhqnmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>56</s> 54+1 bytes

+1 byte for `-R` flag

```php
for(;$z**.5<$n=$argn;$z++)$z%-~$n&&$z%~-$n||print~+$z;
```

prints numbers prepended by dashes. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d9e5edcbb9978dae3a86393f6f4f05a86e62c37).

requires PHP 5.6 or later for `**` operator.
Add one byte for older PHP: Replace `;$z**.5<$n=$argn` with `$z=$argn;$z<$n*$n`.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 45 bytes

```
->n{(n*n).times{|i|i%-~n>0&&i%~-n>0||p(i+1)}}
```

Works internally as zero indexed. checks if `i` modulo `n+1` or `n-1` is 0, if so prints `i+1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
ṁo►L∂Se↔C¹ḣ□
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9odXNr///huYFv4pa6TOKIglNl4oaUQ8K54bij4pah////Mw)

indices are unordered.