# Draw diagonal positions of me squared

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art, matrix

Based on the interpretation user [@ThePirateBay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72349/thepiratebay) made from the **[first version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/140321/1)** of my own challenge

#### [Output diagonal positions of me squared](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140321/output-diagonal-positions-of-me-squared)

now I challenge you to make ASCII art that draws diagonal lines based on a square character matrix  based on a given number `n`.

## Input

A number n.

## Output

A square matrix of size `n^2` which outputs diagonals represented by the adequate one of the `\ X /`chars. All other positions are to be fulfilled with `#` chars.

## Examples:

```
1
X

2
\/
/\

3
\#/
#X#
/#\

4
\##/
#\/#
#/\#
/##\

5
\###/
#\#/#
##X##
#/#\#
/###\
```

There will be no accepted answer. I want to know the shortest code for each language.

Comment: @ThePirateBay: Thanks! Just published it!

Comment: Is outputting a list of lines ok?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder What do you mean by "a list of lines"? Isn't my representation a list of lines?

Comment: No. I meant array, like `["\/", "/\"]` for 2?

Comment: No. It is not valid. I specifically asked for [tag:ascii-art].

Comment: This isn't a dupe. Aside from Charcoal, not a lot of languages can be trivially modified to create a background of `#`'s. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: The background of octothorpes, the `X` in the middle if input is odd and each line in the big `X` is as long as input, not double the size. I think it's not a dupe.

Comment: The output for even inputs makes this not a dupe (along with the other comments)

Comment: I believe this to still be a duplicate. [Here](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xz1GP0JZPTOissQ1QFvz/38TAA) is a trivial change made to the [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125394/71256) on the duplicate question. NB: I don't even know MATL.

Comment: @H.PWiz: Can you prove the reasoning of making a trivial change to a [Draw a big slash X](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125383/draw-a-big-slash-x) answer holds true for a lot of languages?

Comment: No, but it works for all that indexed into a string that looked something like `"\/X "`, e.g [This](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8i2KDEvPVUjM6@gtERDU5MrLb9IIVMhM0@hyKqgKDOvRF1dLys/M09DXTlGP0I9OtPWNsvKyig2uii6LjMWyIkFacgCa9D8/98UAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁼þµḤ+Ṛị“/\X#”Y
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning a list of characters; or a full program printing the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4oG8w77CteG4pCvhuZrhu4vigJwvXFgj4oCdWf///zU)** or see [[1-12] in one go](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//4oG8w77CteG4pCvhuZrhu4vigJwvXFgj4oCdWf8xMsOH4oKsauKBvsK2wrb//zI).

#### How?

```
⁼þµḤ+Ṛị“/\X#”Y - Link: number, n
 þ             - outer product (implicit range build on left AND right from n) with:
⁼              -   is equal (yields a table of 0s except the main diagonal is 1s)
  µ            - monadic chain separation, call that I
   Ḥ           - double (change all the 1s to 2s)
     Ṛ         - reverse I (a table of 0s with 1s as the anti-diagonal)
    +          - add (vectorises to make a table of zeros with 2s on the diagonal,
               -      1s on the anti-diagonal and, if the meet, a 3 at the centre)
       “/\X#”  - literal list of characters ['/','\','X','#']
      ị        - index into (replaces... 1:'/'; 2:'\'; 3:'X'; and 0:'#')
             Y - join with newline characters
               - as a full program: implicit print
```

Comment: Clever approach!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

```python
n=input()
for i in range(n):l=['#']*n;l[i],l[~i]='\X/X'[i-~i==n::2];print''.join(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsIwFAXQ3a8IOLxErIWCS8r7j0LM0MHWK@EmhHRw6a/Hc8qvfTKn3qlgOZp1ly1XAwOaunJ/WzqfNMhV4o1zCoj3FE5EldcyLhIwnFCl91OcSwWbyOObQZtc788/)

-3 thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech) and [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b).

Comment: Your TIO link has a footer artifact.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I realized a version of mine was invalid and quickly rolled back...

Comment: I noticed... :P

Comment: Is not `n/2.-.5` equivalent to `~-n/2.`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech missed that

Comment: And if you multiply instead of dividing you can save another byte: n==1+i*2

Comment: @GB But that is equivalent to `n==i-~i`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I *think* that works. EDIT: yep

Comment: I thought I could steal that for my ruby answer, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>73 61</s> 59 bytes

```ruby
->n{(0...n).map{|x|w=?#*n;w[x],w[~x]=?\\,n==1+x*2??X:?/;w}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNAT08vT1MvN7GguqaiptzWXlkrz7o8uiJWpzy6riLW1j4mRifP1tZQu0LLyN4@wspe37q8tva/hqGenqEBXF9BaUmxQrS6rq6uuk4aUHNs7X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＵＢ#Ｎν↗∕ν²×X﹪ν²‖ＢＯL﹪ν²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxCsIwEADQPV8RIsIFUgTdOnYTREtVcI3x2gbTNJyXgl8fF8X5PTdacrMNpZyRG@ueA805PkCtlBb7mDIf83RHgqhFSz4y1NfU@WFkIzcQjdzqH1z8hC9QN2Xk@itadNgHdNxkZqQ@vE8LUrAJ6sN/lbIr1RI@) Verbose version.

Comment: There's a neat trick to save two bytes by using multidirectional mirrors. In your case, either `L` or `¬` would work, but you would have to draw your line in a different direction of course.

Comment: Note that the deverbosifier allows you to omit the `else`, so what you're seeing there is "if `v` is odd, draw an X and reflect with overlap (so that the X is not itself reflected) otherwise reflect without overlap".

Comment: You can actually save a byte by using `ReflectButterflyOverlap` which takes a second parameter which is the amount of overlap. If you give it an overlap of 0 then you get a `ReflectMirror` and if you give it an overlap of 1 then you get a `ReflectButterfly`.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxCsIwEADQPV8RIsIFUgTdOnYTREtVcI3x2gbTNJyXgl8fF8X5PTdacrMNpZyRG@ueA805PkCtlBb7mDIf83RHgqhFSz4y1NfU@WFkIzcQjdzqH1z8hC9QN2Xk@itadNgHdNxkZqQ@vE8LUrAJ6sN/lbIr1RI@ "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
.↔╝Ζ #ŗ.2%?╬3←╬¡
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=LiV1MjE5NCV1MjU1RCV1MDM5NiUyMCUyMyV1MDE1Ny4yJTI1JTNGJXUyNTZDMyV1MjE5MCV1MjU2QyVBMQ__,inputs=NQ__)

Finally got use out of the fact that palindromizating `/` or `\` on the edge creates `X` (but this could be ~5 bytes less with a couple features I have had in mind for a while (e.g. that overlapping would overlap slashes too and palindomizating commands have the option to choose the overlap amount from the remainder of ceiling dividing))

Explanation:

```
.↔                push input ceiling-divided by 2 (. is required because SOGLs input is taken lazily)
  ╝               create a diagonal of that length
   Ζ #ŗ           replace spaces with hashes
       .2%?       if the input % 2 isn't 0
           ╬3       palindromize with 1 overlap
             ←      stop program
              ╬¡  [else] palindromize with 0 overlap
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 68 bytes

```r
write(c("#","\\","/","X")[(d=diag(n<-scan()))+d[n:1,]*2+1],"",n,,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVI1lDSVlJRykmBkjoA3GEkma0RoptSmZiukaejW5xcmKehqampnZKdJ6VoU6slpG2YayOkpJOng6Q1Pxv8h8A)

Reads `n` from stdin. Creates a matrix of indices `(d=diag(n))+d[n:1,]*2+1` to index into the vector of characters to print, which results in a vector of characters. `write` writes it as a matrix to `""` (stdout) with `n` columns and separator `""`.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
'\/X#'iXytPE+)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xz1GP0JZPTOisiTAVVvz/39zAA)

Explanation: suppose the input is 3

```
'\/X#'               push this character string.
i                    read in input. stack is ['\/X#';3]
Xy                   push nxn identity matrix.
                     stack is ['\/X#'; [1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1]]
tP                   duplicate and flip left-right
                     stack is ['\/X#'; [1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1];
                                       [0 0 1 ; 0 1 0 ; 1 0 0]]
E+                   double TOS and add top 2 stack elements
                     stack is ['\/X#'; [1 0 2 ; 0 3 0 ; 2 0 1]]
)                    index; 1-based modular, so
                     1 -> \, 2 -> /, 3 -> X, 0 -> #
                     implicit output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 103 bytes

```
n=>{for(let i=n,j,s;i--;){s="";for(j=n;j--;)s+=i==j?n-j-1==j?"X":"\\":n-j-1==i?"/":"#";console.log(s)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclNCsIwEIbhvaco4ybBRqn/NIy9hotuSk1KhjKRprgpPXt0wM3DN@9Q9@lSP4X3bDi@XB7dXHgsMuNj8XFScgfkkspkgzFWLwkBrLwI2ZKktMOASA0bMpUMeEINbQv1v4QGDr@yBdtHTnF0@zEOKul1zV5VeuPVUTgJZ@EiXIWbcNf5Cw)

A more readable version with spaces and breaks added:

```
n => {
  for (let i = n, j, s; i--;) {
    s="";
    for (j = n; j--;) 
      s += i == j
        ? n - j - 1 == j
          ? "X"
          : "\\"
        : n - j - 1 == i
          ? "/"
          : "#";
    console.log(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using a return statement instead of logging it.

Comment: Thanks @StephenLeppik, but I thought I had to output the result? Would I have to include "\n" after each line?

Comment: You **do** have to output it, but on this site [your return value is valid output.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2456/62402)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 20 bytes

```
´Ṫ§o!"¦/X#"+=ȯD=←¹+ŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9odXNr///CtOG5qsKnbyEiwqYvWCMiKz3Ir0Q94oaQwrkrxYD///81)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 24 bytes

```
Àé#ÀÄòr\jlò|òr/klòÇÜ/ãrX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4ZXKQKLl8KaimKycw5tqgAz9bCDjcPvhOfqHFxdF/P//3wwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 133 bytes

```python
def f(k,h="#"):s=[h*i+"\\"+h*(k-i*2-2)+"/"+i*h for i in range(k/2)];print"\n".join(s+k%2*[k/2*h+"X"+k/2*h]+[e[::-1]for e in s[::-1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBCsMgEIXhq8iUgjqxIa6KIfcoqItCtU4FDUk2Pb1tml137@fBN7@3VItu7REiizx3aYITCLNONklCcA4wSZ4VSa20QOgBSSYW68KIUWHLvTwDz70WfpwXKhu4ApdXpcJXzGct7feTCeEG@FsebbDGqMHvRtiN9Wgv2h87dFdhIidx0O0D)

A beautiful mess done on mobile :-). If you have golfing suggestions, you are welcome to edit in yourselves (and credit you!), because I will be sleeping :P.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 122 bytes

```python
def f(n):s='\\'+'#'*(n-2)+'/';return['x'][:n]if n<2else[s]+['#'+l+'#'for l in f(n-2)]+[s[::-1]]
print'\n'.join(f(input()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxNCgIhGIb3nUJo8WkyRUIba06i7lIy5FXUgTq946yfn/Lvnww1xtsHFjiEbitZS5LOdOFYlJB0o2f1fasw9CNnNFwMDC/lU/OmOWmmK9NRhFxZYhHHaaYTNaP1cnfuVGpEJwu6fnMEDzyibJ0LIcZ47A)

A recursive aproach

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 114 bytes

```
(s=#;F[x_]:=DiagonalMatrix[Table[x,s]];z=F@"\\"+Reverse@F@"/"//. 0->"#";If[OddQ@s,z[[t=⌈s/2⌉,t]]="X"];Grid@z)&
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 81 bytes

```perl
for$i(0..($n=<>)-1){$_='#'x$n;s|.{$i}\K.|\\|;s%.(.{$i})$%/$1%;s%/%X% if!/\\/;say}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glU8NAT09DJc/Wxk5T11CzWiXeVl1ZvUIlz7q4Rq9aJbM2xluvJiamxrpYVU8DLKCpoqqvYqgKFNBXjVBVyExT1I@J0bcuTqys/f/f9F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQwMA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
：：#×＊；＼：↔１１╋１１╋
```

[Try it online!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjFBJXVGRjFBJTIzJUQ3JXVGRjBBJXVGRjFCJXVGRjNDJXVGRjFBJXUyMTk0JXVGRjExJXVGRjExJXUyNTRCJXVGRjExJXVGRjExJXUyNTRC,i=NQ__)

<sup><sub>could get it to 11 bytes if canvas's overlap function had a default setting but it doesn't so...</sub></sup>

Comment: You don't need the starting `：：` as the stack (practically) contains the inputs repeated forever. And yeah, I need to add a 1 byte built-in for `１１╋`

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 99 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[(2#+Reverse@#+2)&@DiagonalMatrix[45~Table~#]/.{2->35,137->88}]~StringRiffle~"\n"&
```

This uses a somewhat different technique from the other Mathematica solution. Also, we should probably start calling it the Wolfram Language at some point.