# Coffee Machine Machine

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

You left your computer for too long, and it went to sleep. Wake it up again by printing the following coffee maker.

```
________._________
|      | \   -   /
|  ||  |  \  -  /
|  ||  |___\___/
|  ||  |     X
|      |    ___
|      |   / - \
|______|  /  -  \
| ____ | /_______\
||7:30||__________
||____|           |
|_________________|
```

<sup>[Reference image I used.](http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/17/28/1499887621-cuisinart-coffee.jpg)</sup>

## Specs

- Any input must be included in the byte total.
- Leading newlines and trailing whitespace is allowed.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I'm usually fine with different types of KC challenges, but the ASCII art (while pretty good) has no patterns that submissions could benefit from.

Comment: @totallyhuman better now?

Comment: @Pavel that'll be for the microwave challenge.

Comment: Bah, this question changed invalidating the 88-byte answer I had been writing: `7:30⸿⁴↑²←←⁴↓↓²Ｐ¹⁷←↑χ⁸Ｐχ.⸿↘↓²↗↑²Ｍ³→↓²Ｐ⁸↓³Ｐ←⁷↓³↗→χＰ↓³↖ ↑→¹↖²←²Ｐ<⁴←²Ｐ>⁴ＵＭＫＡ⎇⁼-ι_ι_↓x--Ｐ-×_⁴` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHfS8MwEMff/SvCPWWQilsLHVEEUcEHhSHuTRihiy6YJjXr5o9/PrZJadas8y3f@9597i5XbJgpNJPWLoxQNYacphevBiaXZz6Q9S@6rAiaNfJJ7zmmj/ytDl6rCMp6905/qeC2qqvdyVpULjrNT7DaPkUv58OqYMC5nzM0fBbvm3q0q0tZVlHCYKGUIHoaEAaYx3469LuvyEfTxudw0u98CAp1/byeDQgOYEec6XHFLL5UtBS98sf7N@e6OzCrbnVZMrXGC84/bqTEE4JeuFHM/OD7zx2TWwwJECSaOKzcI1xtBfHPwHeSQNTrQRvxq1XNZIMWJd9iB8oakLU22cs/ "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Comment: @totallyhuman Ironically, from my POV, the new version has fewer patterns than the old does. (Also, I keep trying to ping you regarding https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141095)

Comment: @Pavel [the microwave challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149736/the-microwave-challenge)

Comment: Can the program send an unrelated message to `stderr`, or should it only print the coffee maker??

Comment: @luk3yx it should only print to one stream. If you want you can put the coffee maker in stderr, but only one stream should have non-whitespace printed.

Comment: @luk3yx If you didn't ask and OP wouldn't have stated otherwise that would have been allowed by default for code-golf as far as I know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 78 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
≈p⁽.*%θ|»Y?v▼mB8█[=ρļiρKτ¾Γb    2⁴⅟┼¤Μ╬(׀⁾⌠○Yyλ{╝<-³|k¤↑E*UH∙æ¹ΘNσx↔§÷πm‛⁾ņμ׀⁴@≤‘
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMjQ4cCV1MjA3RC4qJTI1JXUwM0I4JTdDJUJCWSUzRnYldTI1QkNtQjgldTI1ODglNUIlM0QldTAzQzEldTAxM0NpJXUwM0MxSyV1MDNDNCVCRSV1MDM5M2IlMDkyJXUyMDc0JXUyMTVGJXUyNTNDJUE0JXUwMzlDJXUyNTZDJTI4JXUwNUMwJXUyMDdFJXUyMzIwJXUyNUNCWXkldTAzQkIlN0IldTI1NUQlM0MtJUIzJTdDayVBNCV1MjE5MUUqVUgldTIyMTklRTYlQjkldTAzOThOJXUwM0MzeCV1MjE5NCVBNyVGNyV1MDNDMG0ldTIwMUIldTIwN0UldTAxNDYldTAzQkMldTA1QzAldTIwNzRAJXUyMjY0JXUyMDE4)

SOGL compression beats bubblegum!

Comment: @totallyhuman the whole thing is a compressed string - it ends with `‘` and there is no starting `"`.

Comment: Well of course it beats Bubblegum, it was designed with ASCII-art in mind :P

Answer (score 20):

## [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), 219 bytes

*Thanks to @totallyhuman for saving 4 bytes!*

```
->"""#{l="________"}.#{l}_
#{s="|      |"} \\   -   /
#{t="|  ||  |"}  \\  -  /
#{t}___\\___/
#{t}     X
#{s}    ___
#{s}   / - \\
|______|  /  -  \\
| ____ | /_______\\
||7:30||#{l}__
||____|           |
|#{l}#{l}_|"""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@xCgMhDIZ3n0Jyy93gWehQKNjn6CA4iFcKUku97eKz2xhtA0r@/zMx8WnbQsj@83zv1bMwVd0AYDqiATcCykq6ODEd2QBKDoQiraVE0dGEdkaIHTFTgxRqYi1dXXH9vXXjlPxfrqnEWoH9X2xGa9Ks9sxJlHoM1Ty8XM8nRB7OkRxF/0DBjDnSVrTjK6cY1pgec993Xpb6BQ)

Comment: The irony of your language is not lost on me.

Comment: This is not ironic. It is apt.

Answer (score 6):

## Befunge, <s>166</s> 162 bytes

```
55+31p"kvvvvvvvvgf:::::kvugvvvvvj6,jHvvvs>?vqg[@:P>vvvg[|P:f::>Jv"v
:0  /\|_-37X.v"vvvv{vvvvg:::>=:@:G>f>f:=|:G>f>fv`vUg:j:>::N>::f::"<
g1+2%+56:-*49<_@#:,g1/+56,
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=NTUrMzFwImt2dnZ2dnZ2dmdmOjo6OjprdnVndnZ2dnZqNixqSHZ2dnM+P3ZxZ1tAOlA+dnZ2Z1t8UDpmOjo+SnYidgo6MCAgL1x8Xy0zN1gudiJ2dnZ2e3Z2dnZnOjo6Pj06QDpHPmY+Zjo9fDpHPmY+ZnZgdlVnOmo6Pjo6Tj46OmY6OiI8CmcxKzIlKzU2Oi0qNDk8X0AjOixnMS8rNTYs&input=)

**Explanation**

This is using a fairly simple compression scheme where every two characters are encoded into a pair as a base 11 number.

We start by translating the characters into indices in a lookup table to minimise their size - this gives us one index in the range 0 to 11, and a second in the range 0 to 8. These indices are combined into a single number as `n = i1 + i2*11`. We then add a additional offset to translate that number into the range of printable ASCII characters, so it can be stored in a Befunge string.

When decoding we just perform this process in reverse. We subtract the offset, split the value into two parts with `i1 = n%11` and `i2 = n/11`, and then lookup those indices in the translation table to obtain the final characters to output.

**Bonus Coffee Mug**

```
55+37p"kvvvvvvvvgf::"v
v",6jvvvvvguvk:::"   <
>"jHvvvs>?vqg[@:P"   v
v"vJ>::f:P|[gvvv>"   <
>"::f::>N::>:j:gU"   v
v"f>f:=|:G>f>fv`v"   <
>">G:@:=>:::gvvvv"   v
:0 X/\|_-37X.v"vvvv{"<
 @v2%+56:-*49<<_>
  >+7g,65+/7g,:^
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=NTUrMzdwImt2dnZ2dnZ2dmdmOjoidgp2Iiw2anZ2dnZ2Z3V2azo6OiIgICA8Cj4iakh2dnZzPj92cWdbQDpQIiAgIHYKdiJ2Sj46OmY6UHxbZ3Z2dj4iICAgPAo+Ijo6Zjo6Pk46Oj46ajpnVSIgICB2CnYiZj5mOj18Okc+Zj5mdmB2IiAgIDwKPiI+RzpAOj0+Ojo6Z3Z2dnYiICAgdgo6MCBYL1x8Xy0zN1gudiJ2dnZ2eyI8CiBAdjIlKzU2Oi0qNDk8PF8+CiAgPis3Zyw2NSsvN2csOl4&input=)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 176 bytes

```js
_=>`22__.222511| 31-1/4636-6/4232/416X511| 12511|1/ - 3522|6/6-635 2_ | /2_235|7:0||222_5|2_|6111|522222__|`.replace(/\d/g,s=>[30,'   ','___','\\',`
|  ||  |`,`
|`,'  '][s]||s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCoMwEETv/Yq9RUGN2ZgUCvodBZWNqJUWUTGlp/13Gz3MsMy8nU/363y/v7dvuqzDeLygPKisHCJRhohGKQatUiULq21qZYEaZaHs82rUBSgJKWiDyFYGRhtAAgaJhNrw/ZEzhykyjMRWhYeAngGxy/Zxm7t@jGQzyCnxZVXrPBEAIBJBRMGbRiTuxgB8yp23OwnR1r5l9vHRr4tf5zGb1yl6RXF8/AE)

## [RegPack](https://siorki.github.io/regPack.html)'d version, <s>186</s> 184 bytes

```js
_=>[...'CaFfEiNe!'].reduce((s,c)=>(x=s.split(c)).join(x.pop()),`!E_.C!
f| \\a-aiN\\e-ei|!\\!iNaX
fNe!
fN / - FCN/e-eF E | /!EF|7:30||CE
||Efea|
|CCE_|E__a N|ei/
N|NE!_fNeeF\\
|ae C!!`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY6xigMhFAB7v@JZRSHrBlIcHGwa0dL64AxGzDMYlnWJSUjx/n1jM83AMPf4ji09yvoclnrFLcO0hen0r5Ta6WizKQ757qweeH0lFKLtk5xO4jM11da5PEWSUt1rWcRHrXUVUu4v3ASlOcsE3schFuc9DliIe8@Li38s92YHjDCA1W7s1oIBgpEbSz@/xwORNozIZIzESGsTyIQQwRGWkTlyhodeQes9o4igOb/ILdWl1RnVXG8i95XtCw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 83 bytes

```
00000000: 4d8c d501 0230 1403 ff3b 4507 c01d 16c1  M....0...;E.....
00000010: c922 199e abf7 9eab 2a2b 3582 63c6 f183  ."......*+5.c...
00000020: 5f62 eb60 4a0c a5b7 9c3b 923e d8bc 028f  _b.`J....;.>....
00000030: f104 e6a7 d89a 0f9f 6065 4c9d 5fd2 8902  ........`eL._...
00000040: 56d6 2ad0 f2f9 b6df d8ea d0aa 671d d75f  V.*.........g.._
00000050: 33fe 03                                  3..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdC9TgQxDATgnqcYUR6S5fxuwkl0NAha2rs4ia@B8p5/8cKio2OkSCmcLyPLVeRjXq6f68p7HhFH6RiJHdgHhoscoBoEMfGCzm7A5e6AN7KwnePzdqO7H8GZ0av3cLVONNEFdTaBb14QUvHIoWeoKwGg@@@ndHhI1G@GNyNp9piSGbFxR0tiULce1YeJUaRbwaLASej8siFHevrTI5ihjiNmbovN1wbWqsicE2Kvw34YHqWytx57zvOVTjcjbj3yyFZ@MNRrheShps2Gwa0hL7aPsSTr8U6HX4YuRKfdSGaEoBO2x38TiNb1Cw)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 189 bytes

```cs
()=>@"uu__.uuu
|ss| \s-s/
|  ||  |  \  -  /
|  ||  |u\u/
|  ||  |s  X
|ss| su
|ss|s/ - \
|uu|  /  -  \
| u_ | /u_u\
||7:30||uuu_
||u_|  sss|
|uuuuu__|".Replace("u","___").Replace("s","   ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BSsQwFEXX5isuWTVgW8GFYJ1hYMCVA6ILXRRCiRkNdBrpyxNkMt9eXx2kuMjinndP4DoqXRz9xBSGdzx/U/KHRrm@I8LjUVHqUnC458HdURqls8Y27vfe7zr3EQaPFabCrNYbzWxtxcwqE2W0VFKtMpDnB7RACSyEW14CAa9njc461dJuVWaWc/2rSgJb@apmyxLyze31VZYGWwlspUhizs7MbNbVk//sO@cLzfpSW2u1WRAJAqDN1Ki/lV8xvGHXhaEw6qgutnGg2PvqZQzJP8jW4t/ywphGndRp@gE)

---

The lazy solution:

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 223 bytes

```cs
()=>@"________._________
|      | \   -   /
|  ||  |  \  -  /
|  ||  |___\___/
|  ||  |     X
|      |    ___
|      |   / - \
|______|  /  -  \
| ____ | /_______\
||7:30||__________
||____|           |
|_________________|"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBCsIwDD2brwietsNU8CA4J4LgSUHwoIfBGLXTgrawVkGM3z5T3XR7kJK@vvcaImwkTCmrm1X6hLuHdfIag7jk1uL2CdblTglc3bSYWVeyZo5LUxRSbnJxVlpiglUQJvNFP6sxaJoMCD8gTPmMuIaeIl/ouajNsCHlaksYh38IoxPKZk5Igb6/kb/7SGa8MGPJsJ6EKZpMxyOirDUd1bYfCFrvNahfxdDs4W7UETe50kEIT@gtjbbmIgf7Ujm55m0End0EYRjDC17VGw)

Comment: @StephenLeppik I'm keen to see a C# way of compressing this that is shorter than the hardcoded solution, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: @StephenLeppik If I go down the `Replace` route I save some bytes, but I'm still thinking that run-length encoding, or decompressing some compressed string will be longer than hardcoding (keen to be proven wrong though).

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <strike>169</strike> 165 bytes

Thanks to [Nahuel Fouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul) for saving 4 bytes!

```bash
base64 -d<<<H4sIAECtIFoCA1WOUQqAMAxD/3uKXmBO8EPwJH4MepEc3sRVrQ86WJZkjZgs8WDwG/jg2ThdEjQurVWFgcGpFnJ+JeRXyjAbhmH+Bt1VSUXGoKXnJpSwH9sKRNkOGXuBlfcEdgGenVY82QAAAA==|zcat
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcHJDkNAAADQX@ldGrFENOEwGMOIKoqpm62EWmqItum/a9/LM9rse57RShIPx1JRFEukNoD6YpujDrjEi/wncMHLYIXVIb3myfCyYUt0qwkWAg3i2ZelBKddm9ZUTowNsW3NX5sStv46x4lZF2gyB8zgKiDvFuRNbzHawsVhRNDokAFP4WadqBOcOw@RVXvcC1jWqBrim8z74E9Vv58iW/b9Bw)

`gzip` seems to compress it a lot better than `bzip2` and `xz`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>282</s> 265 bytes

```python
a,b,c,d,e,u='_ . | \ / ||'.split();s=' ';t=s*2;z=c+t;y=c+s*6;v=z+u+t
for x in a*8+b+a*9,y+c+s+d+s*3+a+s*3+e,v+z+d+t+a+t+e,v+c+a*3+d+a*3+e,v+c+s*5+"X",y+c+s*4+a*3,y+c+s*3+e+s+a+s+d,y+z+e+t+a+t+d,c+s+a*4+s+c+s+e+a*7+d,u+"7:30"+c*2+a*10,u+a*4+c+s*11+c,c+a*17+c:print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NDoJADITvPkXDBd02yo@Kutn38GBi1gUjiQHCLkYI745d8NJ0vk5nmt696iqZJk0PMpRTQZ0K77CFEW6wg3EMt7Z5l269kVaFEEqnrEjkoAw62fO04ig/asAO3epZt/CFsgItTvhALc7UI1swZ1uKep4FfXBg4li7WRl2pkz0/@pDDxhcg@Vb7P3lv7OD87TPZDKwWnJy8j2avXZuLHjPmHYYZJc0CtCIhFEcMfEunxXHaMiXxxmaS9OWlYPvNP0A)

Actually a fair bit longer than just

```python
print'''TheCoffeePot'''
```

which would be 227 but it works so posting it anyway as it's the shortest (and so far only) Python answer :)

Comment: You can shave of a few bytes from that first line: `a,b,c,d,e,s='_.|\/ ';u=2*c;t=s*2;z=c+t;y=c+s*6;v=z+u+t`

Comment: @DanielHepper - many thanks but I don't think this is going to go under 200 so have had enough of this challenge now. Will remember your tips for next time and thanks again :)

Comment: Actually in python 2 print '''the coffee pot''' [doesn't work](https://tio.run/##VU/BCoAgFLv7FeLdjDoEfUkHwWtdSsJLsH@3vbKywUTnNp/xSPO2djnHfVmTMSYUNM8mKOgL0J6rJZ1IEGrRbK0w4MnaQkxfCfErZZgNXuF@DXKWSipiDLS4MgklDGPfAqGaDiX2Aqq6LwC/lvMJ) because of the backslashes at the end of the line, you have to escape them which costs you 3 bytes, [giving a total of 230.](https://tio.run/##VU/BCoAgFLv7FeLdjDoEfUkHwWtdSsJLsH@3vbKyweQxt/mMR5q3tcs57suajDGhoHmGoKAvQHuelnQiQahFs7XCgCdrCzF9JcSvlGE2eK9wPwcRpFMksQaaXNlFNAxj3wKhWhAl@AKqui8Af5fzCQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 689 bytes

```
+++++++++>+++>++++++++++++>++++>+++++++++>+>++++>++++>++++>+++++>+++++>++++++++>+++++<<<<<<<<<<<<[[->>>>>>>>>>>>>>++++++++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>]>+++++>++>++++>+++++++>++>>+++++>++++++>++++++++>+>+++++>++++++++>++++++++<<<<<<<<<<<<........>>>>>>>.<<<<<<<.........>>>>>.<<<.<......>.<.>>>.<<<...>>>>>.<<<<<...>>.>>.<<<.<..>..<..>.<..>>>.<<<..>>>>>.<<<<<..>>.>>.<<<.<..>..<..>.<<...>>>>.<<<<...>>>.>>.<<<.<......>.<.....>>>>>>>>>>.<<<<<<.<<<.<......>.<....<...>>>>>.<<<.<......>.<...>>.<<.>>>>>.<<<<<.>>>.>.<<<.<<......>>.<..>>.<<..>>>>>.<<<<<..>>>.>.<<<.<.<....>.>.<.>>.<<<.......>>>>.>.<<<..>>>>>>>>.>>.<<<.<.<<<<<<..<<..........>>>>>.<<<..<<....>>.<...........>.>>>.<<<.<<.................>>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLCkIxEDuQmBOUXOTxFioIIrgQPH/9dD6ZUgdaOmlIMnN@nm6P6@ty7/3gRTsFEIQCyJfe8WhS23ZkqXRopXbuIVa8v32x4ZRptp@kYWX@mGAECsM@DRySb@uQZGLcDckv9DXbVRGaSvMEEjlTL0jt3wgYoiXRz2oQnWnxsQgf3CFL2wxye0xShM1ZfNGybIlqMH1YTx6jKBxhe38D)

First I generate a table of 13 characters that are used. To save bytes, I first generate their closest character codes that are divisible by 10. Then I add 0-9 to each of them. Finally I just print them in particular orders.

Unminified source:

```
+++++++++>+++>++++++++++++>++++>+++++++++>+>++++>++++>++++>+++++>+++++>++++++++>+++++<<<<<<<<<<<<
[[->>>>>>>>>>>>>>++++++++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>]
>
+++++>++>++++>+++++++>++>>+++++>++++++>++++++++>+>+++++>++++++++>++++++++
<<<<<<<<<<<<
........>>>>>>>.<<<<<<<.........>>>>>.
<<<.<......>.<.>>>.<<<...>>>>>.<<<<<...>>.>>.
<<<.<..>..<..>.<..>>>.<<<..>>>>>.<<<<<..>>.>>.
<<<.<..>..<..>.<<...>>>>.<<<<...>>>.>>.
<<<.<......>.<.....>>>>>>>>>>.<<<<<<.
<<<.<......>.<....<...>>>>>.
<<<.<......>.<...>>.<<.>>>>>.<<<<<.>>>.>.
<<<.<<......>>.<..>>.<<..>>>>>.<<<<<..>>>.>.
<<<.<.<....>.>.<.>>.<<<.......>>>>.>.
<<<..>>>>>>>>.>>.<<<.<.<<<<<<..<<..........>>>>>.
<<<..<<....>>.<...........>.>>>.
<<<.<<.................>>.
```

Comment: Nice but seems to miss out the 3rd || on the 5th line

Comment: You can change the initialization to `++++++++++[>+++++++++>+++>++++++++++++>++++>+++++++++>+>++++>++++>++++>+++++>+++++>++++++++>+++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<-]`. And after adding 0-9, use `[<]>` to get back to origin. That would save 37 bytes.

Comment: And round to nearest would save another 19 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBdCoNADIQPJJkTLLmI@GALBRH6UPD8627zu7Bt0JKMH9NJHp/9eL@u51nr4rWyt6zvIGSJpefl32/qSi7anBIXIuq9qtTHrvjcnrVsDC2Wgtph0LsK1doAk9JnnRBwsy6CBz/gc9pc4Z4ZswQpcqSeQOXXChDTIdH3rwQ0UuNjEt5ZsWW9DOJ6HJCHjV3s0OnYKarKbMtacl8lyx621hs "brainfuck – Try It Online")

Comment: Good stuff. Since brainfuck only understands eight symbols, I contend that this solution is only 258 and three eighths of a byte long.

Comment: @Fax That would be for binaryfuck.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>174</strike> 164 bytes

Some silly RLE-like compression, lengths encoded as base 99 number :)

```
_19]\(10#.inv 99x#._28+a.i.'Ls}DR#Er-B{SBh(+dXQwBE=]|LrC$v:x5u}sa"z>f=#Y*?Tzzo8PmK7rZay')#,'_._||\-/|||\-/|||_\_/|||x||_||/-\|_|/-\|_|/_\|7:30|__|_| ||__|',.' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYdLD8FAFEb3fgNxYyTj0Y4iQicpSemKhdcCGblpMEGCpA2qbn97VcLiO@d851SHjgQLsqXYtLeq0rSYOF0fYNsRE9jq1X1xErwwCZPRnHmB6b4X7rFS369mT9dztlSYBMPyQ0adexL6pbif1w5b1wbLuBjfetPLuBts/BevMoOjQCJlNuhPVPhVlBVRw1SZfkRFXdm2CDF7QF9zQ3DgaTVXEsC1I7kBiQQd5g674w10@gE)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 546 bytes

```
-[+>+[+<]>+]>>++++++++++>------->-[<++>-----]<........<<.+>>.........<.>>>++++[<++++++++>-]--->--[<+>--]++>-[<+>-----]+++>-[<+>---]<<<.<......>.<.<---.>...<<<--.++>>>...<<<.>.>>>.<..>..<..>.<..<.+++>..<<<--.++>>>..<<<.>.>>>.<..>..<..>.<<...---.+++...<<.>.>>>.<..>..<..>.<.....>>>.<<<<<.>>>.<......>.<....<...<.>>>.<......>.<...<<<.>>>.<<<--.++>>>.<---.+++<.>>>.<<......>>.<..<<<.>>>..<<<--.++>>>..<---.+++<.>>>.<.<....>.>.<.<<<.>>.......---.+++<.>>>..>++.+++.-------.---.<..<<..........<.>>>..<<....>>.<...........>.<<<.>>>.<<.................>>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFLCkMhDDxQMCcIcxFx0RYKpdBFoee3@enTx8tC85lJJnr/3l6f5@/x7r1UAlWSBmoATUMJQ6kyoiacJsIE8AwZwTXs4DdnG13PZplwi0dH2ES7ZWeoI5pj@BB1WZHISLPmi@HiFLut2Ql9DbYhxUEUO1z1MxWWFO8BrNJ81Vx3z0/wokJy1qgkPlQn/iR7Z8QIxKs4Id97g7G@vK@UP@ZVH8H7B43UoX0sILvEtQju/Q8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>220</s> <s>216</s> 213 bytes

```
b=0;c='\n -./037:X\\_|'
for i in r"*Z_7stu{NzKBNJ,IOOe-0qj9?s7C?r/XYUX_Fs\hM-\NY+VJ+A.E]?vAx&=gUVSBRq4>PB+]OtO3%PWn%^0c0'B]d5P-$X,(7U$nVq02NRjMp'AAvl!Da(zyVyI":b=b*92+ord(i)-32
while b:print(c[b%13],end='');b//=13
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc//ToJAAADg/32Ky0mHAnJCjYm7GFht2gRmg7COWAcU59zxMwvr3a3vDb6q74qS6@czxWiRYkg4UKYq0g0zIiT5hYP3sgEMMA6a4eQ5Mdru88c9PTjuWl55Xq6gej@3WmNpNWq0C6LkviXFRiHuTgrXkj29i62j/X2JP4Lw0dnWVze@I8Ve5@mC/8SFV5Qi6MTZta@MIlk0ghEPa6S52/2mgrZ9PFzcvomnPuxXQ5NiOplrUtlkIhsrujb4KtghB9SsGsY7MX2hwkyP5ZxnGMLxgqoqnv23/gA)

[Code to generate code](https://tio.run/##VZHrboMwDIX/5ykspIqkNyhMmkrFnmNSqRCBbDBBQIHd1OzZmcOlpZaM4OT4sx2a3y6vpd/3aQUhWJYVT7GfX2KiYQgNET53mI6RtEkw2m6pYEGEubRgvN4hGA9QLEZCFBE9ttNGMEwjGWuMJmeaxWj6OfBdrePFgHoqvIUmi/MpNG5H0jxRLW5aFm1H21p1IqOt6GhaMcYISdpYflZcKLS45K1WUEAhQYkvoVq0oi0gAHfbGlFC0gHLHk42IQzqvpCZ@KGFoZdNnnDRIfyc5go1uLdI5LugvreFg/fELqRE0w1GJIx9ZgIj/HhAzbbJd16UAsoX1wwGMOqz71yu5AU2Rh1OS3CcECQhaZ2J8Yfz0D2l4fVvsa11/bMCHvL10dvUKsM5d743NeJBowqJF3bmq4N/2QqZhbbNThzBBx95e@RUSUeVaBTFz4@6mO@Hbc0geBETAmdgpO//AQ)

Comment: `print(c[b%13],end='')` can be `print(end=c[b%13])` for -3 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically), <s>652</s> 626 bytes

```
⇒@@@@@@@@
RU+532f1-411@+411f1@-3320@+5432@-4422@@@@@@+4422@-4422@+220@-220@@@+4-0@-4+0@@@+1@-4000@+5432@-4422@@+4422@@-4422@@+4422@-4422@@+220@-220@@+4-0@-4+0@@+1@-4000@+5432@-4422@@+4422@@-4422@@+4422@-50+4@@@-1+00@+1-00@@@-50@-4000@+5432@-4422@@+4422@@-4422@@+4422@-4422@@@@@+311@-333@+5432@-4422@@@@@@+4422@-4422@@@@+510@@@-3320@+5432@-4422@@@@@@+4422@-4422@@@+1@-1@+4-0@-4+0@+220@-3311@+5432@-50+4@@@@@@+50-4@-4422@@+1@-1@@+4-0@-4+0@@+220@-3311@+5432@-4422@+510@@@@-510@+4422@-4422@+1@+50@@@@@@@-1+00@-3311@+5432@@-52@+1-00@-3+4@-1+00@+541@@-50+4f1@@-3320@+5432@@-50+4@@@@+50-4@-4422f1@@@+4422@-5432@+5432@-50+4f1f1@+50-4@
```

Found via [this tool](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141839/61563) and golfed via search-and-replace, plus a couple custom optimizations.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJBCgIxDLz7lRBomvTeNwg@QBcWhL168AXefaIfqUlTd1sFxT10kzKTzCSdLqfzdFyWaymP2z23b7c/QOI4EwpRBj1mysgcQ4YkHDOKxOhYqKFfQFQE2mH3qLFAjZUtIbyxnTlmr2Qr1NX5o0wKINoYCQxOGEyG3v6pw7QzVe/83bqliWqX33NyK9R5c8NsvRqzOah1A8oqrxKHqXxQfReuRgvpf1iS4ULbtA@oZyshtokhq4Q2wiSUXdRMo8dNaifUQOsuDNW5mu01ObaUJw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 108 bytes

`zcat`

Input is a 104 byte sequence on stdin (represented in hexadecimal below) of the coffee pot compressed in gzip format:

```
1F 8B 08 01 0F 2D 32 5A 02 00 5D 8C 41 0A 80 30
0C 04 EF 7D 45 3E A0 15 3C 08 BE C4 43 20 1F D9
C7 3B B1 96 56 87 A6 90 21 BB F1 B2 46 A7 C8 1E
64 CE BF 30 35 95 18 9E A3 66 43 C0 99 F9 04 AE
51 02 9F 52 C2 34 78 11 16 94 3B 22 8D 05 70 52
A3 81 D2 71 EE 9B B8 ED A0 5A 6C 20 BA FE A8 DC
9E 9D 56 3C D9 00 00 00
```

Comment: Might as well be Bubblegum.